# Propriedade x Atributo

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, característica-linguagem, propriedade, atributos

Uma `propriedade` de uma classe não é a mesma coisa que um `atributo`?

Qual a real diferença entre eles?

Ou `propriedade` é um sinônimo para `atributo` ou vice-versa?

Ou varia conforme a linguagem de programação?

Comment: Atributo é o termo da UML para aquilo que implementamos como propriedades da classe (ou do objeto) no nosso código.

Comment: Existem os atributos do `C#` -> `[DllImport("user32.dll")]` -> [Atributos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/z0w1kczw.aspx)

Comment: Sim, para definição de metadados de elementos da classe ou metadados da própria classe. Veja que a própria Microsoft usa o termo "atributo" quando fala em desenhar classes usando UML: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323861.aspx. É bacana escolher uma linguagem coerente no seu projeto, mas não é errado quando alguém alterna os termos "atributo" e "propriedade" para se referir à mesma coisa.

Comment: @MeuChapeu Só para deixar claro, você está falando de UML ou linguagens de programação em geral? Eu entendi o que você queria? Ou o que você quer é outra coisa?

Comment: @bigown, Não estou falando de UML e sim de linguagens de programação em geral.

Comment: @MeuChapeu Não se preocupe com a UML, ela é só dos indicadores de que os termos são intercambiáveis. Eu adicionei uma resposta com bastante evidências disso, sem mencionar nenhuma vez a palavra UML ;-) Boa leitura.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> **Atenção!** Isto começou considerando apenas o contexto do C#, mas agora depois de pesquisa concluo que o que está escrito nesta resposta vale para qualquer linguagem de programação, talvez exceto Smalltalk. Me desculpe, mas a outra resposta está cheia de coisas mal pensadas, repetidas sem análise e criticidade, produzindo falácias. Eu posso estar errado, mas me contestem com fatos, com informações que façam sentido. Repetir os erros dos outros não ajuda.

## Introdução

Tem uma [pergunta na rede](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28085/1362) que fala de forma genérica mas cita um exemplo na área de TI.

Para o uso em desenvolvimento de software, especialmente em orientação a objeto como especificado, isso pode depender da linguagem que está usando.

Procurei os termos em âmbito da orientação a objeto e nada confiável foi achado. Achei alguns lugares, de novo, não confiáveis, onde intercambiam os dois termos como se fossem a mesma coisa, além da confusão já indicada anteriormente. [Isto é canônico e confiável](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mitra/csSpring2015/cs303/lectures/oop.html)?

## C#

Em C# claramente a [propriedade](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (*property*) é um membro de uma classe que fornece uma informação sobre o objeto/classe. Na verdade a propriedade em si é um método. Muitas vezes ela acessa o estado que está efetivamente em um campo (*field*) (algumas vezes chamado também de variável de classe ou de instância), é o que se chama padrão de projeto de métodos acessador/modificador (*getter* e *setter*).

[Atributo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (*attribute*) não tem nenhuma relação com isto. Ele é usado para marcar ou modificar classes e métodos adicionando informações relevantes que podem ser usados pelo compilador, utilitários ou mesmo a aplicação em tempo de execução.

Se você intercambiar os termos propriedade e atributo, vai confundir o interlocutor e vai ter que ficar dando explicações desnecessárias. Isto quando não causar algum problema maior.

Note que a linguagem possui vários atributos prontos e que fazem parte da sintaxe dela conforme especificação. Além desses atributos existe um mecanismo onde você pode criar e usar seus próprios atributos que são aqueles que são usados com colchetes para desambiguar com outros nomes.

## Java

Em Java a [propriedade](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) é o mesmo que no C#, acredito que podemos dizer que vale para todas linguagens orientadas a objeto. Mas há uma diferença de implementação já que outras linguagens não possuem a propriedade como uma característica da linguagem em si. Ela pode ser emulada criando par de métodos acessador/modificador.

Em Java há um [atributo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/Attribute.html) que é usado de forma semelhante ao C# mas não tem isso claro na especificação da linguagem. O atributo existe, só não está clarificado, afinal um `public` é um atributo da linguagem em Java e em C#. Um `static` também, quando usa o tipo de um campo está usando um atributo de tipo para aquele campo, o mesmo para o nome do campo, sim, isto é um atributo.

Se as variáveis da classe são atributos porque a [classe de reflexão](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) tem um método chamado `getFields()` e não tem um `getAttributes()`? Tem um `getAnnotations()` que é como Java chama os atributos.

O mecanismo de atributo personalizado pelo programador é chamado de anotação.

#### Termo errado

Atributo costuma ser usado para indicar o campo, mas é um termo errado. O uso do termo atributo é pertinente em outros contextos mas não em classes. Em Java é muito comum as pessoas falarem atributo para se referir ao campo, mas a [documentação da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html) não usa este termo (pelo menos não usava, pode ser em em partes novas, especialmente escritas pela comunidade possa usar o termo, mas é um erro, e é terrível que a documentão ensine errado, por isso tome cuidado, nem na documentação pode confiar, até pode mas só na parte que foi escrita por profissionais cuidadosos.

Provavelmente o termo foi disseminado por livros e cursos feitos por quem não entende ou não se preocupa com a qualidade do conteúdo, que não quer ensinar o jeito correto, apenas o jeito que resolve.

Claro que em algum contexto o termo pode estar correto. Como UML citado nos comentários, mas não é o caso do que a maioria das linguagens de programação *mainstream* usam. Acredito que este é o motivo de usarem errado, se em UML faz sentido o uso do termo então achama que  de forma genérica faz sentido também, mas fica inconsistente com o que as linguagens adotaram. Como em geral as pessoas trabalham em cima de linguagens o tempo todo e não tratam de forma genérica eu acho que deveriam mudar o termo em outros contextos, ou deixar de usar uma ferramenta como UML (muitas pessoas estão deixando).

## Outras linguagens

Outras linguagens provavelmente usam os termos de um jeito próprio. C++, por exemplo, usa o termo propriedade de forma análoga ao Java, e atributos são modificadores existentes na linguagem, mas você não podia criar um, agora pode.

Em Python uma propriedade é uma forma especial de atributo para acessar estado, mais ou menos como nas outras linguagens. O atributo é tratado mais formalmente como o membro que guarda o estado.

Em alguns lugares vi o termo propriedade ser usado para os campos diretamente. Há linguagens que podem usar os dois termos de forma intercambiável. Então sua conclusão é correta, depende de linguagem sim.

## Resumo

O termo propriedade é a forma que acessa uma característica do objeto e atributo é a forma errada de se referir à variável de instância onde o estado é efetivamente guardado, o campo (falo mais detalhadamente em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)). Mas isso varia de linguagem para linguagem. Acostume-se usar o que a comunidade específica usa, mas aprenda o termo correto. O mais importante é se comunicar bem com as pessoas que usam a ferramenta que você usa. Então acostume-se usar o termo dentro de cada contexto.

**Membro** se refere à qualquer elemento dentro de uma classe (na verdade qualquer tipo, já que algumas linguagens possuem tipos que não são classes). Alguns membros são **campos**, frequentemente confundido com atributos em algumas comunidades. Este campos são **variáveis**, que podem ser **de classe** ou **de instância**. Métodos especiais para acesso aos campos (com sintaxe própria ou não) são chamados de **propriedades**.

## Referências

Um [artigo interessante quando escolher um ou outro no C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/properties-vs-attributes?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Que mostra como pode ser confuso se usar os termos errados.

Wikipedia:

- [Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_%28programming%29)
- [Attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_%28computing%29)

## Contestação

A outra resposta fala sobre outro assunto não relacionado com a pergunta. Ela está certa, em sua maioria. Não concordo que os termos sejam intercambiáveis mesmo no nível conceitual, e se fossem não precisaria existir dois, muito menos acho que atributo é o mesmo que campo, já que faria que atributo, campo e propriedade fossem a mesma coisa. É insano afirmar isto. Eu entendo que na prática usa-se os 3 como se fossem uma coisa só, justamente porque as pessoas não sabem sobre o que é, mas é errado dizer que é a mesma coisa. E quem não entende os termos corretos acaba produzindo soluções incorretas de forma até sutil.

**Para entender o conceitual vá em** [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 12):

## Definição

Linguagens de programação modernas e de alto nível não servem para nada senão para expressar um modelo, expressar regras do domínio, então um diálogo conceitual é importante para quem quer se aprimorar como desenvolvedor.

> Em Orientação a Objetos, "atributo" e "propriedade" são termos que podem ser intercambiáveis.

Isso porque "atributo", conceitualmente, é uma característica que um objeto carrega, e em várias linguagens orientadas a objeto (**Java**, **C#**, **Ruby**, **Smalltalk**), propriedade é a implementação deste atributo, a sua exposição controlada para o mundo exterior ao objeto.

Este conceito de que "propriedade" é uma maneira de implementar um "atributo" em uma classe ou objeto nos trouxe a prática de dizer que **atributo é um campo interno da classe**. E isso não está errado.

## Evidências - Atributo como campo da classe ou objeto:

Veja este *paper* do Martin Fowler: [Dealing With Properties](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/properties.pdf) (ou "Lidando com propriedades"). Neste artigo ele se refere a "atributo" como sendo um campo da classe, algo que será consumido externamente como uma propriedade.

Veja também estes dois artigos sobre Smalltalk: [Smalltalk Object Model](http://www.objs.com/x3h7/smalltalk.htm) e [Smalltalk basics - Definitions, Nomenclature and Concepts](http://live.exept.de/doc/online/english/getstart/tut_2.html). Eles também tratam atributos como campos internos da classe ou objeto.

Veja ainda a [maneira de declarar propriedades em Ruby](http://ruby.about.com/od/oo/ss/Using-Attributes.htm), a palavra chave é prefixada com **attr** (de **attribute**). Exemplos:

```
def Pessoa
    attr_accessor :nome # propriedade leitura e escrita
    attr_reader :cpf # propriedade somente leitura
end;
```

## Evidências - Atributo como termo intercambiável com propriedade:

Quando definimos nosso modelo de objetos, é natural falarmos apenas das características e comportamentos de um objeto, ou seja, não falamos sobre seus dados internos que sejam do interesse apenas do código dentro da classe.

Isso ocorre porque os dados internos do objeto são detalhes de implementação e não são do interesse por exemplo dos especialistas em negócio.

Em seu livro [Domain-Driven Design](http://www-public.int-evry.fr/~gibson/Teaching/CSC7322/ReadingMaterial/Evans03.pdf), Eric Evans usa o termo "atributo" para falar das características dos objetos de negócio. Exemplos:

- *"Objeto Valor: Um objeto que descreve algumas características ou **atributos**, mas não carrega conceito de identidade."*
- *"Quando você mudar qualquer um dos **atributos** na Especificação de Rota, nós vamos deletar o Itnerário antigo."*

Em seu legendário livro [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://www.uml.org.cn/c++/pdf/DesignPatterns.pdf), a "gangue dos quatro" alterna o uso dos termos "propriedade" e "atributo" para se referir à mesma coisa, por exemplo:

- *"Equipamento declara operações que retornam os **atributos** de uma parte do equipamento, como o seu consumo de energia e custo."*

Em seu livro [The Pragmatic Programmer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/020161622X), Dave Thomas também alterna os termos "atributo" e "propriedade" para se referir às características de um objeto. Por exemplo:

- *"Digamos que nossa análise revele que, entre outros **atributos**, um caminhão tem um tipo, um número de licença, e um motorista.*"

## Atributo ou propriedade nas linguagens de programação

Se formos desenvolver uma solução em **Ruby**, vamos definir os acessadores para os nossos **attributes** (a palavra é reconhecida pela linguagem).

Se formos desenvolver em **VB.Net** ou **Delphi**, vamos criar **properties** (a palavra é reconhecida pela linguagem).

**Java e C#, por sua vez, sequer usam nem o termo "propriedade" nem o termo "atributo" na linguagem** para se referir àquilo do que estamos tratando aqui (estes termos são conceituais e não estão presentes na linguagem).

## Conclusão:

No nível conceitual, é comum dizer que atributos são as característica da classe ou objeto, os dados que o objeto carrega.

Historicamente a gente vem fazendo isso, e não apenas as ferramentas ruins ou pessoas ruins fazem isso, mas sim também ferramentas e pessoas bem conceituadas, antigas ou modernas, como demonstrado nas referências desta resposta.

No nível de programação, implementamos atributos como propriedades, controlando sua exposição para o mundo exterior.

Finalizando, há que se subir para o nível conceitual para dizer o que é atributo e o que é propriedade, pois cada linguagem tem particularidades quanto ao uso destes termos (isso quando elas se referem a estes termos, porque algumas delas não os utiliza na linguagem de fato).

Esta resposta procurou demonstrar que ambos são a mesma coisa, principalmente no nível conceitual dos nossos objetos e que, ao descer para o nível da linguagem em que o domínio é implementado, podem surgir particularidades quanto ao uso dos termos, mas que estas particularidades não devem ofuscar o entendimento do que a expressão **"objeto e seus atributos"** significa numa solução orientada a objetos.

Comment: Se eu entendi direito, você argumenta basicamente que "propriedades" são variáveis dentro de um programa qualquer, ou seja, um mecanismo para implementar o conceito de atributo da orientação a objetos. Certo? Se meu entendimento tá correto, eu curti a resposta e concordo com ela. Eu também defendo que atributo e propriedade são sinônimos porque, do ponto de vista conceitual, um atributo/propriedade é algo que uma classe/objeto *tem*, e um método/*handler*/função é algo que uma classe/objeto *faz*.

Comment: Essa metáfora é util pra entender que não importa a acessibilidade (público, privado, protegido) de um atributo/propriedade ou método/função, os conceitos são únicos. Cada linguagem tem liberdade pra escolher como mais bem facilitar a vida do programador, e se alguma escolhe usar, por exemplo, `property` pra definir um atributo que *já tem* *getters* e *setters*, melhor para o programador. Mas não muda o conceito.

Answer (score -1):

Na linguagem C# e VisualBasic a palavra "atributo" tem outro significado:

**Atributo (attribute)**

Atributos fornecem um método poderoso de associar metadados ou informações declarativas, com código (assemblies, tipos, métodos, propriedades e assim por diante).

Depois que um atributo estiver associado a uma entidade do programa, o atributo pode ser consultado em tempo de execução usando uma técnica chamada reflection.

Atributos adicionam metadados para o seu programa. Metadados são informações sobre os tipos definidos em um programa.

Todos os assemblies .NET contêm um conjunto de metadados que descrevem os tipos e seus membros. Você pode adicionar atributos personalizados para especificar qualquer informação adicional necessária.

Você pode aplicar um ou mais atributos à assemblies, módulos ou elementos pequenos do programas como classes e propriedades.

**Campo (field)** <*talvez um atributo em outras linguagens de programação*>

Um campo é uma variável de qualquer tipo que é declarada diretamente em uma classe ou struct. Em geral, você só deve usar campos para variáveis que têm acessibilidade particular ou protegida. (Não pode ser acessada externamente)

**Propriedade (Property)**

Uma propriedade é um membro que oferece um mecanismo flexível para ler, gravar ou calcular o valor de um campo particular. As propriedades podem ser usadas como se fossem membros de dados públicos, mas na verdade elas são métodos realmente especiais chamados acessadores. Isso permite que os dados sejam acessados facilmente e ainda ajuda a promover a segurança e a flexibilidade dos métodos. (Pode ser acessada externamente)

**Veja exemplos práticos:**

Atributo (attribute)

```
[System.Serializable]
```

Campo (field):

```
string _nomeUsuario;
```

Propriedade (property):

```
public string NomeUsuario { get; set; }
```