# É uma prática ruim usar interfaces vazias?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, interface

Já ouvi comentários que seria uma boa ideia, quando pode ocorrer uma implementação futura.

Já ouvido dizer também que é uma prática ruim.

Eu sei que no PHP, por exemplo, existe uma interface chamada [`Traversable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), que não possui nada. Ela serve apenas para identificar que um objeto pode ser usado pelo `foreach`.

- É uma prática ruim usar interfaces vazias?
- É aceitável fazer isso apenas para fazer indução de tipos, como no exemplo abaixo?

  interface AcceptableInterface {}

  class Acceptable implements AcceptableInterface{}

  function is_acceptable_class($object)
  {
  return ($object instanceof AcceptableInterface);
  }

  is_acceptable_class(new stdClass); // false
  is_acceptable_class(new Acceptable); // true

Comment: Não devemos implementar diretamente `Traversable`, ele é utilizado internamente pelo PHP somente: http://3v4l.org/vho4J . Você deve utilizar  `Iterator` conforme a documentação - http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php

Comment: Citei `Traversable` como exemplo de interface vazia, mas valeu pela informação :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

É o que eu sempre falo, boas ou más práticas dependem do caso. O termo, infelizmente, é usado para criar manuais, "o jeito certo de fazer", e assim as pessoas começam seguir as coisas cegamente. Tudo pode ser bom ou ruim dependendo do contexto. E o contexto envolve uma quantidade inimaginável de variáveis, incluindo aí aspectos técnicos e políticos, passando pelas pessoas que estão trabalhando ou trabalharão no projeto.

As tais das boas práticas têm causado mais problemas que ajuda, já que a maioria das pessoas seguem essas "regras" como se fossem algo que deve fazer sempre.

Então já adianto que não tem problema algum em fazer isso se você tiver um bom motivo e souber o que está fazendo. Se entender o problema que pode causar se fizer assim. E quase tudo pode causar problema em maior ou menor grau. Se não souber o que está fazendo, não faça. Nem comece programar seriamente se não souber **como** programar :)

## Marker Interface

O que esta interface faz é marcar uma classe para dizer algo sobre ela. Isto tem nome: [Marker interface pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern).

Interfaces são para indicar que uma classe tem uma determinada capacidade. Daí é possível interpretar de duas formas: a interface deve dizer sempre qual é a capacidade que ela está se referindo, ou seja, deve indicar pelo menos um método que a classe que a implementar deve ter; ou ela apenas precisa indicar algo na classe para dar semântica.

Se tivesse um grande problema ou fosse totalmente contra o que a linguagem permite, obviamente seria proibido ter interfaces com zero membros. Como não é, você pode usar quando achar adequado.

Em determinados contextos, ou seja, em determinadas equipes, ou em determinadas linguagens pode ser que isto seja mal visto. Pode ser considerado um [*code smell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Mas *code smell* não é o mesmo que *code rotten* (acho que inventei o termo :P). Ele não deve ser evitado a todo custo, sob pena de gerar outro *code smell*. Ele apenas deve ser evitado, tem uma diferença aí.

Por exemplo, tem linguagens que possuem [atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101). Nesses casos é melhor usar esse mecanismo. Nas linguagens que não possuem isso, o padrão Marker Interface pode ser utilizado como simulador do atributo. Ele tem até algumas vantagens. Alguns dirão que é abuso, outros dirão que é mais vantajoso que o atributo porque pode ser verificado em tempo de compilação. Mas isto não vale muito para o PHP. E também pode verificar o atributo em tempo de compilação com alguma ferramenta.

## Mas que problemas causam?

Sei de um problema: é que todos os descendentes terão esse marcador. Com o uso do atributo (também chamado de anotação) isso não ocorre. Você pode querer isso ou não.

Em PHP, dada a filosofia da linguagem e dada as inúmeras falhas bem mais graves na linguagem, eu diria que não é um grande problema usá-lo, mas não abuse.

Ele pode ser usado como documentador. Aí acho exagero mesmo. Precisa ter uma função clara no código. O código não está claro e não pode melhor isso? Use comentário.

Ele pode ser útil em aplicações que precisem usar [programação orientada a aspectos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Do ponto de vista conceitual, de orientação a objeto, não é comum fazer assim. Diz-se que a interface deveria ter algum membro.

## Conclusão

Nós só podemos falar em recomendações, e como disse, isso depende de contexto. Evite, mas se precisar mesmo, vá em frente. Eu particularmente acho que sempre dá para viver sem ele. Mas em códigos mais complexos pode ser uma mão na roda se não houver mecanismo melhor.

Antes de usar alguma coisa você deve encontrar uma boa justificativa. Se você encontrar uma, souber o que está fazendo, pode usar, mas tente achar outra forma antes.

É uma pena que o trecho apresentado não dá uma clara indicação do seu uso. Eu acredito que está sendo usado como uma forma de [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276112/101) e provavelmente alguma técnica de implementação de aspectos (AOP).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não tinha pensado nesse problema: "Toda classe que herdar a classe que implementa a interface vazia, vai 'ter' ela de uma forma ou outra"

Comment: Boa resposta (gostei particularmente da menção ao padrão *marker*). Além do mais, do ponto de vista de manutenção (que parece ser o principal argumento a favor de se usar interfaces vazias implícito na questão), numa necessidade futura a implementação de uma interface nova e a sua utilização (implementação) por parte de uma ou mais classes existentes é bastante trivial. De fato, se chegar ao ponto de que uma interface faltou para um grande número (ou uma grande hierarquia) de classes, provavelmente já se errou desde o começo. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira sem dúvida, e se fez uma grande hierarquia provavelmente errou também :P

Comment: @bigown Ditto. :)

Comment: @bigown, sua resposta lembrou um colega meu: "Tudo depende"

Comment: Ótima resposta, mas parece que a conclusão dedura-a como baseada em opinião... :S

Comment: @KaduAmaral não chega ser, é quase. Dizer que é gosto, que depende, é algo objetivo. Dizer que gosto disto, eu acho isto, é pura opinião. Você pode por um pouco de opinião desde que tenha algo objetivo que sustente a resposta, a opinião precisa ser secundária, se ela for retirada, a resposta tem que sobreviver.

Comment: De fato @bigown, foi só no final mesmo que ficou um "gostinho" de opnião, mas opiniões de quem entende do assunto geralmente são bem vindas. +1

Comment: Cunhando novos termos :P, já da para escrever um livros de boas práticas ou anti-patterns hehe, com direito a um loongo capitulo  sobre exceptions :).

Comment: nem comentários se faz necessario nessa resposta...rsrsrsr

Answer (score -2):

Não é nem uma boa e nem uma má prática, é apenas uma prática, a resposta acima diz muito e estou apenas adicionando a minha como uma tentativa de complemento para abrir sua cabeça para outras ideias.

Como foi dito, uma interface acabará sendo propagada para classes filhas que interface pai for definida, técnicamente falando, é uma péssima prática já que dado que a interface em seu papel principal é criada para gerar um contrato de responsabilidade entre voce e sua classe, mas isso não quer dizer que seja uma péssima prática, pois a interface por outro lado mesmo que vazia isso ajuda a manter uma certa hemogenia do seu código e ajuda futuramente no futuro para a escalibilidade da sua interface que ai entra no [SOLID Patterns](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design) onde o primeiro principio é que toda classe deve ter uma unica responsabilidade e a sua interface ajudaria isso no futuro ou no momento.

E como foi dito na resposta acima isso é uma das grandes tristezas que temos no PHP infelizmente, devido ao alto dinamismo da linguagem e ela não ter sido construida em cima de sólidos paradgimas acaba ficando tudo meio esquisito e até mesmo soando errado em muitos aspectos se formos olhar sobre os paradigmas de orientação a objetos e etc...

E como foi citado acima, você tem alguma razão para fazer isso? Se sim, ok, mas você sabe o que está fazendo?

Eu vim da galera do C++ então muitas coisas de orientação a objetos e paradigmas são bem enraizadas na minha cabeça e quando eu vejo PHP funcionando dessa forma me dá até arrepios.

Agora uma parte mais da trajetória profissional em relação a sua pergunta:

E mesmo com 8 anos de PHP eu nunca fiz isso que você está perguntando, e não é por ser errado ou certo como foi dito acima, boas práticas não são verdades absolutas. 
Eu não fiz porque eu vi sentido, como eu falei, interfaces são contratos, se tu tem um contrato que mesmo que ele extenda de algum outro contrato existente então para que tu ta fazendo um contrato intermediario em cima de um que já existe?

Por exemplo, voce tem a interface x que extends alguma Interator da vida, ok, mas sua interface x é vázia e voce nao tem perspectiva de que ela realmente vá virar algum contrato no futuro. Como foi dito acima, todas as classes que herdam da pai vão acabar herdando essa interface e isso pode virar de uma coisa simples sem sentido a uma brutal dor de cabeça para você.

Particulamente, eu sempre fui o cara orientado a boas soluções, onde eu faço o mix entre boas práticas com boas soluções, mas eu jamais deixo de favorecer a boa prática em cima da solução, nem todo code smells é um code rotten como foi citado acima e nem todo go horse é um code smells.

Tudo vária e dependerá do seu contexto e um dos principais lemas da orientação objetos é contexto, então técnicamente voce nao está errado, mas sempre na escalibilidade da sua aplicação, pense nesse codigo daqui 10 meses e principal pense se tu ia gostar de ver isso daqui a 10 meses dessa forma.