# O que são anotações e qual sua definição?

Tags: java, annotation

Anotações são tipos de interfaces ou constitui um tipo próprio?

E sendo assim, qual sua definição e finalidade?

`@Override`, `@Deprecated` e `@SuppressWarnings` são tipos de anotações?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html

Answer (score 5):

[`@Override`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22913/101) ([documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Override.html)), [`@Deprecated`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Deprecated.html) e [`@SuppressWarnings`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) são [anotações](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation).

## Não faz parte da linguagem

Note que a biblioteca padrão de Java tem alguns atributos personalizados (anotações) criadas para seu uso, mas eles não são atributos da linguagem, e sim da biblioteca padrão, conforme especificação da linguagem. Eles foram criadas com classes de um jeito específico, e você pode criar outros atributos personalizados para sua aplicação da mesma forma se isso for necessário.

## O que é

Anotações são atributos personalizados que os usuários (os programadores que usam Java) podem criar para usar em situações que eles podem ser úteis para dar mais informações ao código que não seja possível de outra forma, e elas carregam informações que podem usar usadas por ferramentas ou mesmo dentro do código.

## Finalidade

Diversos mecanismos do ecossistema de Java usam eles para fornecer algo adicional que seja necessário para o mecanismo, principalmente ORMs (veja exemplos como o Hibernate como ele os usa), mecanismos de geração de páginas HTML, etc.

Eventualmente pode ser usado por alguma ferramenta ou até entendido pela implementação do compilador de Java que está usando (diferente de ser da linguagem), como é o caso do `@SupressWarnings` ou do `@Deprecated` que também é usado por alguns geradores de documentação. E claro, sua aplicação pode ter algum mecanismo que faça uso específico disto, ainda que eu perceba que quase ninguém consegue criar algo assim, apenas usam o que já existe na biblioteca padrão ou de alguma pronta que ela escolheu usar.

Eles podem ser usados para dar algum contexto extra para pacotes, classes, campos, métodos, parâmetros e variáveis.

## Como funcionam

Essas anotações vão junto do código através de [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101) quando a aplicação é gerada e podem ser consultadas com [API específica](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/package-summary.html), em geral com o mecanismo de [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/506768/101) da linguagem.

Para criar uma interface que seja uma nova anotação não tem nada de especial além de indicar com `@` que ela é uma interface marcadora para anotação, apenas deve colocar dentro os campos que essa anotação terá, que pode ser nenhum. Depois de criar e documentar, poderá usar onde quiser e for útil. Elas são consideradas [*marker interface*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76511/101).

Os dados delas são imutáveis pelo código normal. Não achei nada que indicasse ter como mexer nos valores por reflexão, até porque não costuma fazer sentido mexer neles.

## Anotação é um atributo

Note que ele cria um novo atributo para usar onde já tem alguns atributos, e eu tenho que pedir para entender [o que de fato é um atributo já que provavelmente aprendeu o termo errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). É muito comum, especialmente entre programadores Java terem aprendido que o campo chama atributo, mas isso está errado, mesmo que tenha até em livros. Alguém aprendeu errado, ensinou errado e quase todo mundo usa errado. A [especificação de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) está correta.

Sendo assim quando usa:

```
@Deprecated
public int idade;
```

Você tem um campo com alguns atributos, na primeira linha tem um atributo personalizado, que Java chama de *Annotation*, e depois na segunda linha o primeiro (`public`) é o atributo de visibilidade, depois tem o atributo (`int`) de tipo do campo, e finalmente tem o atributo (`idade`) que define o nome do campo. Então em tese esse campo não deveria ser usado mais, provavelmente porque tem um campo de data de nascimento que é melhor, mas ele está mantido por compatibilidade já que é público e pode ter sido usado em outros códigos.

Veja comentários abaixo para entender melhor a questão destes elementos da sintaxe serem atributos, além de alguns serem classificados também como modificadores em uma análise mais específica.

Eu questiono um pouco, sem discordar abertamente, que a especificação considere a anotação como um modificador, na maioria das vezes ela não modifica nada. Mas oficialmente ela é.

## Exemplo

Peguei um exemplo do [Java T Point](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-annotation):

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;  
import java.lang.reflect.*;  

//criando a anotação
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) //são anotações usadas para criar anotações
@Target(ElementType.METHOD) //só permite usar em métodos
@interface MyAnnotation { //note o @
    int value();  
}  

//usando-a
class Hello {  
    @MyAnnotation(value = 10)  
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("hello annotation");
    }
}  
  
//pegando dados dela
class TestCustomAnnotation1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Hello h = new Hello();
        Method m = h.getClass().getMethod("sayHello");
        MyAnnotation manno = m.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println("value is: " + manno.value());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YKtAEo). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/updoavdcgz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Interface/Annotation.java).

Comment: Maniero, no exemplo que vc deu, acredito que dizer que @Deprecated e public são atributos pode causar confusão. Isto porque a especificação estabelece que eles são **modificadores**, não atributos. É diferente de C#, por exemplo, onde o conceito de atributo realmente existe. Este é um exemplo de onde anotação é descrita como modificador: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1 O que vc acha?

Comment: @wldomiciano eu posso adicionar alguma informação para deixar ainda mais claro mas em qualquer linguagem eles são atributos, mesmo que a especificação não diga isso. Na verdade, o termo atributo está em um nível de classificação acima na taxonomia. `public` é um modificador, `int` não é um modificador. É debatível se `@Deprecated` é, não é debatível que está na documentação, o que *pode* ser um erro dela. Todos eles são atributos do campo. Então não posso colocar que eles são modificadores. Então eu posso melhorar a informação sobre os fatos e falar sobre o que eu acho que pode ser um erro.

Comment: leia o *link* onde eu explico porque as pessoas usam o termo atributo de forma errada e como ele é usado em quase todos os lugares, e não como algumas pessoas descrevem informalmente. Então eu posso melhorar meu texto só pra deixar isso mais claro, mas não colocar uma informação errada que eles não são atributos. C# apenas tem isso de forma mais explícita e usa o termo no lugar de anotação. O que acha?

Comment: Eu gostei muito daquela sua resposta sobre atributos e já tinha marcado como útil em outra ocasião. E eu gosto de pensar em "atributo" como "um termo que está em um nível de classificação acima na taxonomia" como vc descreveu no comentário.

Answer (score 4):

Anotações são metadados do programa (são [ortogonais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/112052) a ele).

Segundo a [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6), uma anotação é um "tipo especial de interface":

> *An annotation type declaration specifies a new annotation type, a **special kind of interface type**.*

<sup><sub>Claro que podemos debater se realmente é um "tipo de interface", já que o comportamento é bem diferente. Mas fiquemos com a definição oficial...</sub></sup>

Para criar uma anotação, usa-se a sintaxe `@interface` (que é diferente de `interface` - sem o `@` - pois aí estamos criando uma interface):

```java
// com o "@", é uma anotação
@interface MinhaAnotacao {
}

// sem o "@", é uma interface
interface MinhaInterface {
}
```

No caso de `@Override`, `@Deprecated` e `@SuppressWarnings`, são anotações pré-definidas pela linguagem - tanto que estão descritas na [seção "*Predefined Annotation Types*"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4). Para saber o que cada uma faz, consulte a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/index.html).

---

As anotações podem ser aplicadas à classes, métodos/construtores, campos, variáveis locais, parâmetros de um método, pacotes e até outras anotações. O que cada uma delas faz, pode variar bastante. No [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html) são citados os seguintes usos:

- Informações ao compilador: por exemplo, `@SuppressWarnings` faz com que os *warnings* do compilador não sejam mostrados.
- Processamento em tempo de compilação: ferramentas podem ler as anotações (sem necessariamente executar o código) e usar as informações delas (por exemplo, gerar relatórios informando todos os lugares em que a anotação X é usada, etc)
- Processamento em tempo de execução: as anotações podem ser usadas em *runtime* para definir algum tipo de comportamento específico.

Só para citar um exemplo, se você usa JPA, existem anotações que podem ser colocadas nas classes que representam entidades:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_users")
public class User implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "username")
  private String name;
}
```

Quando o código for executado, ORM's como o Hibernate saberão (através das anotações) que esta classe refere-se à tabela `tb_users` do banco de dados, e que o campo `name` corresponde à coluna `username` desta tabela. É assim que ele consegue gerar queries SQL automaticamente quando usamos esta classe em uma query JPQL.

Existem outras, como por exemplo `@Transactional`, que define que determinado método executará dentro da mesma transação do banco de dados, etc. Há inúmeros frameworks/libs que fazem uso extenso de anotações para definir determinados comportamentos e/ou configurações.

Então se você criar sua própria anotação, terá que escrever também um [código que verifica se determinada classe/método/etc possui aquela anotação](https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation#processing), e aí decidir o que fazer com essa informação ([exemplo do código fonte do Hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.1.5/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/ColumnsBuilder.java#L86)).