# O que é POD, POJO, POCO?

Tags: java, c#, c++, terminologia, engenharia-de-software

O que significa estas siglas? Por que é útil saber isso? Quando sei se devo usar uma dessas coisas? Elas servem para outras linguagens? Existem outras siglas? Por que tem várias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genericamente pode ser conhecida como PDS (*Passive Data Structure*), é uma forma de indicar que está usando uma estrutura de dados normal da linguagem sem que ela precise de alguma condição especial para tratamento de dados. Quer dizer que é uma estrutura trivial, sem firulas além dos dados.

Na sua forma mais básica é dizer que apenas se trata de um registro de dados com campos que guardarão informações da forma mais simples possível, de tão simples que seria igual ao que uma `struct` em C faz. Costuma-se dizer que não tem características de orientação a objeto nela.

Muitas vezes ela é usada para fazer IO de dados de alguma forma. Por isso algumas pessoas dizem que ele é um [DTO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31362/101), que não é exatamente a mesma coisa, POD é algo mais amplo, um DTO se vale da técnica de POD. Algumas pessoas usam o termo para diferenciar justamente o que é objeto da infraestrutura de objeto do domínio da aplicação.

Cada linguagem pode ter sua própria definição e algumas até precisam, por exemplo Java só pode (ou podia dependendo da data que esteja lendo isso) criar classes, então ela não pode ter uma PDS original, e ela usa o termo POJO (*Plain Old Java Object*) para indicar que apesar de ser uma classe, aquele objeto não será usado para ferramentas específicas de forma especial, não precisa colocar informações extras nos dados através de [anotações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/571176/101).

De forma semelhante é POCO em C# (*Plain Old CLR Object*, alguns preferem o uso de *Class* para não ficar preso a uma tecnologia), embora a linguagem possua tipos simples por valor, ainda se comportam como objetos de OO, tanto que até esses tipos derivam de [`Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Em C++ pode ser chamado de POCO (*Plain Old C++ Object* ou *Plain Old Class Object*), ou POD (*Plain Old Data*), mas a documentação hoje chama apenas de trivial.

Existem regras específicas do que não pode ter na definição da estrutura para ser considerada com esses nomes. Se conter qualquer uma dessas características ele já é uma estrutura complexa.

Usamos isso para identificar se precisa se uma infraestrutura mais complexa, se depende de um *framework* (ORM por exemplo), ou de algo mais avançado da linguagem (polimorfismo e construtores por exemplo), que limita a interoperabilidade com outras partes do sistema ou outros sistemas, por exemplo o sistema operacional.

Em Java por exemplo, pode exigir que os únicos métodos sejam *getters* e *setters*, além de não usar anotações. Tem tecnologia específica que usa o termo de forma diferente, então ele acaba não servindo para indicar bem do que estamos falando. Um termo não pode ser usado assim porque termos servem para explicar de forma simples em uma palavra ou expressão algo que todos, de certo círculo, entendam sem precisam de uma explicação maior.

C++ considera os tipos básicos da linguagem como POD, tinha até na documentação até mudarem para trivial, embora o conceito seja o mesmo.

Os termos não são usados por muitas outras linguagens, em alguns casos porque não se importem em comunicar melhor a intenção, ou não precise na origem da linguagem que deveria ser só fazer cosias simples, mas o conceito ainda pode estar presente lá.

Em resumo, é o objeto que não precisa de "mágica" para conseguir entregar o que precisa.

Mas há definições bastante divergentes. Nem sempre o termo é entendido da mesma maneira pelas pessoas.

Ele é preferível sempre que possível, embora na prática, especialmente em Java e C#, são usados mais quando alguma tecnologia exige ou encoraja, ou ainda quando vai fazer um DTO. Em C++ quando vai interoperar com algo externo ele se torna não só uma coincidência de ser, mas fundamental, já que C++ tem uma forma muito característica de montar objetos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).