# Diferença entre "Atributo" e "Variável de Instância"

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, variáveis, terminologia, atributos

Lendo alguns livros e artigos sobre introdução a Java e OO percebi que esses termos não ficam bem definidos. Procurando mais a fundo encontrei definições diferentes em diferentes fontes sobre o assunto. Qual é a diferença real entre esses tipos de variáveis? Como isso influencia durante o processo de programação?

Comment: Quais fontes são diferentes?

Comment: [Propriedade x Atributo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/91)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Informalmente os termos são **quase** intercambiáveis mesmo. Até certo ponto.

O termo atributo é amplamente difundido em linguagens de modelagem como UML. E é comum os programadores Java se referir às variáveis como atributos do objeto, mas formalmente não são. [O termo sequer consta da documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html).

Onde está lendo atributo, comece ler campo, porque é isto que está dizendo quando falamos em linguagens de programação. Para as linguagens [atributo é outra coisa não relacionada com o que está sendo falado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). É a estória da mentira repetida tantas vezes que passou "ser verdade".

Raramente usa-se o termo campo na comunidade Java, mas ele está presente na documentação *linkada* acima.

Algumas pessoas preferem o uso de "variáveis de instância" para evitar confusão com outras coisas que podem usar o termo "atributo".

Se são variáveis de instância elas estarão presentes em cada objeto desta classe. Já variáveis de classe são os <strike>atributos</strike>campos que estão presentes na própria classe e são compartilhados por todos objetos dela.

Estritamente falando, campo é um termo mais geral, assim como "membro" que inclui os campos e métodos da classe.

Um campo pode pertencer à classe ou à instância. Um campo sempre usa uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) (ou constante) como mecanismo (nunca vi diferente). Então existem variáveis de instância (pertence ao objeto) e variáveis de classe (pertence à classe).

> Como isso influencia durante o processo de programação?

Na programação em si influencia nada, influencia o processo de comunicação. Todos envolvidos precisam entender do que está se falando. Se as pessoas não entendem do que está se falando elas não executarão corretamente, ou o farão por coincidência, por isso eu bato tanto na tecla de usar os termos corretos, isso influencia no resultado final. Alguns acham que é teoria boba, mas afeta a prática sem a pessoa perceber.

Se deseja que crie uma coisa e escreve outra, aí a pessoa que recebeu a informação usa um método que não resolve o problema, a culpa é sua que não usou o termo correto. Se ela criar um campo estático também foi falha de comunicação. Se usar a terminologia corretamente, dentro do contexto, e a pessoa usar errado, a culpa é dela que não sabe o termo correto.

Muitos livros, blogs, e outras fontes usam o termo sem pensar na necessidade da precisão e no contexto que está sendo usado. Em muitos casos, pode não causar confusão, em outros causam mesmo.

```
public class Exemplo {
    private String info1; //variável de instância que é um campo
    private static String info2; //variável de classe que é um campo
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/InstanceVariable.java).

Veja [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101).

Answer (score 2):

Em orientação a objetos Atributo é uma propriedade ou também conhecido como campo ou váriavel que são pertencentes a uma classe, que são usadas para dar caracteriticas a uma classe, como no exemplo abaixo onde temos a classe Carro com três atributos cor, marca e nome que são suas caracteristicas nesse exemplo.

```
public class Carro {

    //Aqui são os atributos da classe Carro
    private String cor;
    private String marca;
    private String nome;

    public String getCor() {
        return cor;
    }

    public void setCor(String cor) {
        this.cor = cor;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

Variável de Instância como o nome já diz é uma instância sendo ela criada a partir de uma Classe, seguindo o mesmo exemplo da classe Carro, poderiamos ter várias instâncias dessa classe onde em cada uma delas teriamos seus atributos definidos de forma diferentes como no exemplo a seguir:

```
public class MeuCarro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Carro carro1 = new Carro();
        carro1.setCor("Azul");
        carro1.setMarca("Mitsubishi");
        carro1.setNome("Mitsubishi L200 Triton");

        Carro carro2 = new Carro();
        carro2.setCor("Preto");
        carro2.setMarca("Ford");
        carro2.setNome("Ford Ranger");

        System.out.println("Carro 1:");
        System.out.println("Cor: " + carro1.getCor());
        System.out.println("Marca: " + carro1.getMarca());
        System.out.println("Nome: " + carro1.getNome());

        System.out.println("\nCarro 2:");
        System.out.println("Cor: " + carro2.getCor());
        System.out.println("Marca: " + carro2.getMarca());
        System.out.println("Nome: " + carro2.getNome());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Atributos pode ser vistos como as propriedades dos objetos, definidas pela sua classe. Podemos dizer que a classe carro define um atributo cor, que é a cor do carro. Quando um objeto carro for instanciado, uma variável de instância será designada para alocar a cor do carro que pode ser, por exemplo, azul.