# Quais são as boas práticas na validação de campos?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, validação

Criei um exemplo para ilustrar a minha duvida a respeito de validação de campos, o exemplo é composto de duas classes `Pessoa` e `ModelPessoa`. A classe `Pessoa` possui os seguintes atributos: `Nome`, `Idade`, `Endereco`, `Salario` e `Cargo`, e a minha classe `ModelPessoa` possui o método `int ValidarCampos(Pessoa funcionario)` este método é o responsável para fazer a verificação dos campos conforme a regra de negocio.

As regras definidas como exemplo para fins de ilustração da dúvida são as seguintes:

- *Nome é obrigatório*;
- *Endereço é obrigatório*;
- *Cargo é obrigatório*;
- *Salário deve conter valor acima de zero*;
- *Funcionário tem que ser adulto*;

Este é o escopo do método `ValidarCampos` definido conforme as regras acima:

```
public int ValidarCampos(Pessoa funcionario) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcionario.Nome)) //Verifica se há conteúdo na variável.
        return 1;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcionario.Endereco)) //Verifica se há conteúdo na variável.
        return 2;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcionario.Cargo)) //Verifica se há conteúdo na variável.
        return 3;
    if (funcionario.Salario <= 0) //Verifica se o valor do salário é valido.
        return 4;
    if (funcionario.Idade < 18) //Verifica se o funcionário é maior de idade.
        return 5;

    return 0; //Todos os campos atende os requisitos das regras.
}
```

Abaixo é a implementação do método `ValidarCampos` e das duas classes:

```
Pessoa funcionario = new Pessoa();
ModelPessoa mp = new ModelPessoa();

Console.Write("Nome: ");
funcionario.Nome = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

Console.Write("Endereço: ");
funcionario.Endereco = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

Console.Write("Cargo: ");
funcionario.Cargo = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

Console.Write("Salario: ");
funcionario.Salario = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Idade: ");
funcionario.Idade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

switch (mp.ValidarCampos(funcionario)) 
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Nome é obrigatório.");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("Endereço é obrigatório");
        break;
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine("Cargo é obrigatório.");
        break;
    case 4:
        Console.WriteLine("Salario deve conter valor acima de zero.");
        break;
    case 5:
        Console.WriteLine("Funcionario tem que ser adulto.");
        break;
    default: 
        Console.WriteLine("Cadastrato com sucesso."); 
        break;
}
```

Este é todo o código do meu exemplo para vocês reproduzirem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ValidacaoCampo
{
    class Pessoa 
    {
        //Todos os campos (atributos) são obrigatorios.
        public string Nome { get; set; } 
        public int Idade { get; set; }
        public string Endereco { get; set; }
        public double Salario { get; set; }
        public string Cargo { get; set; }

        public Pessoa() 
        {
            Nome = "";
            Idade = 0;
            Endereco = "";
            Salario = 0;
            Cargo = "";
        }
    }

    class ModelPessoa 
    {
        public ModelPessoa() { }

        public int ValidarCampos(Pessoa funcionario) 
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcionario.Nome))
                return 1;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcionario.Endereco))
                return 2;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcionario.Cargo))
                return 3;
            if (funcionario.Salario <= 0)
                return 4;
            if (funcionario.Idade < 18)
                return 5;

            return 0;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Pessoa funcionario = new Pessoa();
            ModelPessoa mp = new ModelPessoa();

            Console.Write("Nome: ");
            funcionario.Nome = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

            Console.Write("Endereço: ");
            funcionario.Endereco = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

            Console.Write("Cargo: ");
            funcionario.Cargo = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

            Console.Write("Salario: ");
            funcionario.Salario = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Idade: ");
            funcionario.Idade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (mp.ValidarCampos(funcionario)) 
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Nome é obrigatório.");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Endereço é obrigatório");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cargo é obrigatório.");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Salario deve conter valor acima de zero.");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("Funcionario tem que ser adulto.");
                    break;
                default: 
                    Console.WriteLine("Cadastrato com sucesso."); 
                    break;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

A minha dúvida é a respeito de como fazer as validações dos campos de forma que o código não se torne repetitivo e difícil de ler, dentro das boas praticas de programação ou se existe algum **pattern** que possa ser utilizado na validação dos campos? O método acima é até cabível, mas, se caso eu tiver uma tabela com muitos campos e a maioria dos campos exigir algum critério ou regra de validação, como poderia ser feito a validação sem deixar o código mau estruturado, difícil de ler e repetitivo?

Comment: Dois comentários que não têm propriamente a ver com o que questionas: "há" do verbo "haver" ("Verifica se a conteúdo na variável.") e "if (funcionario.Idade < 18)" ao invés de "if (funcionario.Idade <= 18)".

Comment: Obrigado, não tinha reparado nisso.

Comment: Você está usando ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Estou usando uma arquitetura baseada em camadas, porem é bem parecida com o MVC, mas o foco deste arquitetura em camadas é aplicações Desktop.

Comment: Relacionada: [Usar validação via cliente é suficiente?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13298/usar-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-via-cliente-%C3%A9-suficiente)

Comment: @Laerte o sistema que estou desenvolvendo é para desktop.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Códigos de erro

Primeiro tenho que dizer que não gosto muito da solução que retorna os códigos de erro. Ela não está totalmente errada e é melhor que lançar exceção, o que muitos programadores fariam porque seguem receita de bolo. Gostei da criatividade. Mas códigos numéricos assim são ruins para identificar o que realmente é o erro. Em um exemplo simples e aprendizado é ok. Mas em código em produção não é muito.

Esta enumeração poderia indicar o tipo de invalidade que ocorreu e não em qual propriedade ela ocorreu. Pra isto precisaria modificar um pouco a validação.

Repito, que é aceitável que se use assim, mas eu mudaria para pelo menos usar uma enumeração no lugar de números sem significado.

Ou criar classes de invalidades que são parecidas com exceções mas sem ter a exceção.

Até retornar uma *string* com o erro já seria melhor que retornar um código numérico. Embora não em todos os cenários.

Eu criei um [par de pergunta e resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101) sobre isto, que é uma postagens minhas que mais gosto.

## Modularização

A forma usada para validar não está errada, mas não segue os preceitos da modularização, da orientação a objeto, como gostam alguns. Cada validação deveria estar em seu próprio método.

Há até quem defenda em alguns casos que as validações individuais deveriam estar em classes próprias e não em uma classe só. Isto pode ser um exagero ou não. Se fizer isto, é mais fácil intercambiar as validações. Pode usar o [*Strategy pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), por exemplo. Talvez outros padrões podem ser necessários para compor a criação do objeto de maneira adequada.

Mas precisa se perguntar se isto é necessário, assim como se é necessário ter a `ModelPessoa`. Tem que ter motivos para aumentar a complexidade da aplicação.

Não é nenhum absurdo tê-la, mas se não puder justificá-la é porque está fazendo sobre-engenharia. O fato de você alterar uma classe, obrigar modificar outra, nem sempre é uma boa ideia. Mas há casos que não dá para fugir disto sem desorganizar o código. Me parece que `Pessoa` já é seu *model*.

O que muitas pessoas fazem, e pode ser certo ou errado dependendo do contexto, é criar classes para para propriedade com tudo o que ela precisa, cada propriedade é auto-suficiente em um tipo próprio. Isto costuma ser considerado um anti-padrão que eu não lembro o nome agora. Faz algum sentido, mas pode ser exagerado, principalmente se estiver fazendo isto sem ter consciência da necessidade real.

Esta forma pode ser vantajosa por deixar perto tudo o que se refere àquela propriedade. Mas teria que fazer uma mudança que faria sentido mesmo se a validação estiver dentro de `ModelPessoa` ou dentro de `Pessoa`. A validação feita através de um método por propriedade poderia encapsular tudo o que precisaria ser validado para aquela propriedade, e teria um só lugar para mudar quando algo na propriedade mudar.

Por outro lado, a validação poderia ser incluída dentro da propriedade, especificamente dentro do `set`. Claro que existe uma diferença semântica entre fazer isto e ter um método separado. Dentro da propriedade ela nunca poderá estar em estado inválido, e pode precisar disto eventualmente. Além do que você fica restrito a informar a invalidade por exceção. Ainda acho que a solução melhor é ter métodos de validação. Você tem mais controle.

Mas nem toda validação pode ser feita só na propriedade. Há validações globais, que complicam este cenário de aproximar a validação do seu estado.

## Atributos

Uma outra forma de deixar a validação mais próxima da propriedade sem criar classes individuais para cada propriedade é usar [atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101). Para isto precisa de uma biblioteca deles.

## Método falho

Esta forma usada na pergunta é bem ruim inclusive porque se a primeira propriedade está inválida, ela vai informar este problema e mais nenhum outro. Funciona, mas dá uma experiência ruim. Teria que retornar uma lista com todos os erros, ou um código numérico que opere como *flags* booleanas para indicar quais erros ocorreram em cada bit, ou mudar completamente a forma de lidar com a validação.

Um [`yield`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/101) poderia ser uma solução, mas não resolve de todo.

## Construtor e inicialização

Como última nota paralela, já que eu sei que quer aprender direito, se está usando C# 6, o [construtor é desnecessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) já que ele permite inicializar propriedades. Mesmo em versões anteriores ele pode ser substituído por inicializações dentro da classe, mas o código ficaria maior porque teria que deixar de usar a propriedade padrão e inicializar o campo privado que ela encapsula. A `ModelPessoa` certamente não precisa do construtor.

## Biblioteca

Agora entrando mais no assunto direto da pergunta, você poderia criar uma biblioteca de validações que costumam acontecer. Mas ela teria que trabalhar com uma parâmetro que seria a propriedade a ser validada. Não daria para trabalhar com o objeto todo. Até existe uma gambiarra, mas que não traria vantagem alguma.

Isto pode ser útil para manutenção inclusive porque se houver uma forma diferente de fazer aquela validação específica, mudou na biblioteca, mudou para toda a aplicação.

Isto se chama abstração. Vamos dizer que começou usando `IsEmpty()` para validar. Aí um dia descobre que o `IsNullOrEmpty()` era melhor. Imagine ter que procurar por toda aplicação e mudar isto. Um *search* global pode ajudar mas precisaria analisar manualmente cada caso, nem tudo seria validação, algum lugar pode ter feito o mesmo tipo de validação de uma forma diferente. Se estiver abstraído/encapsulado em um lugar fica fácil resolver.

Outro exemplo: se mudar a idade da maioridade. Ou se a verificação está *bugada*. Esta informação deveria estar em apenas em um lugar. E pode existir maioridades diferentes para cada caso, tudo isto tem que ser pensado. Quase ninguém pensa nessas coisas. Quando pensa, normalmente já é tarde demais, o software já está todo desorganizado. Programar é muito difícil e por isso existem tantos softwares cheio de *bugs*. É comum, mesmo os melhores programadores, não conseguirem enxergar todo o problema. Claro que os mais experientes sabem criar escapatórias fáceis sem gerar complicação.

Isto é fazer [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), que é uma das coisas mais importantes da programação.

Vai dar um ganho muito grande em validações simples assim, conforme pede a pergunta? Não. Mas o DRY, a abstração, não existe para tornar o código menor. Ele determina que a alteração seja necessária em apenas um ponto.

O ganho pode ser maior em validações mais complexas. Mas essas tendem a poder ser menos reaproveitadas.

#### *Frameworks*

Esta biblioteca pode ser feita em forma de atributos. Mas seu uso começa fazer sentido em [*frameworks*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101). Porque a validação não ocorrerá sozinha. Algum mecanismo terá que garantir que ela seja feita. Isto pode ser obtido em um *framework* existente, ou em um que você irá criar. Já existe [algo mais ou menos pronto no .Net](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0). Não estou dizendo que é a solução definitiva e que deve adotá-la sem pensar. Tudo tem lá seus problemas.

O *framework* pode automatizar a verificação da validação. Pode pegar as mensagens de erro, por exemplo. Embora se mudar o código de erro para uma classe de erro, isto já pode ser melhorado, aí você teria algo assim:

```
Console.WriteLine(validacao.MessageInvalidation);
```

Isto é uma bela generalização. No caso teria um classe de erro que uma das propriedades de erro seria `MessageInvalidation`.

Ele pode fazer um laço para executar todas as validações necessárias e isto ficar escondido dentro dele.

Mas fazer um *framework* não é tarefa simples, em geral pessoas inexperientes cometem tantos erros que pode trazer mais prejuízo que benefício.

E *framewoks* mal feitos podem engessar a aplicação.

Cada interface com o usuário pode precisar de um *framework* diferente, mesmo quando o usuário é indireto.

Note que isto ajuda o consumo das validações e não a sua criação, que é o foco da pergunta.

Ainda que use uma biblioteca, isto não pode substituir uma abstração. Afinal você tem que ter uma forma de mudar as validações individualmente de forma canônica.

## Validações variantes

Uma hora você começa se deparar com problemas mais complexos, o que até inviabilizaria a solução de validar dentro da propriedade e até de atributos. Há casos que a validação da criação do objeto é diferente da alteração dele, e até depende do tipo de alteração. Pense nisto. Qualquer solução genérica tem que considerar todos os cenários possíveis.

E as validações que são interdependentes. Já pensou nisto?

Em geral as pessoas têm muita dificuldade em criar softwares genéricos. E quando vão fazer erram a mão não só por esquecer de certos aspectos, mas também por abstrair coisas desnecessárias gerando complexidade à toa. Isto se reflete no uso do paradigma orientado a objeto. É muito difícil acertar o ponto, daí eu costumo dizer que quase ninguém sabe programar neste paradigma. Mesmo eu pensando em tudo isto erro bastante. Imagine quem não domina o assunto.

## *Design pattern*

O padrão mais próximo que posso pensar que pode ajudar um pouco, mas não quer dizer que vá eliminar repetições, é o [*Specification pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). Mas se abusar, ele pode se tornar um fardo. Isto pode dar um outro olhar em como a validação pode ser feita.

Outro que pode ser usado, é basicamente o que os atributos fazem, é o [*Decorator pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Outro é o [*Visitor pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Eles e o *Strategy* me parecem melhores que criar esse tal `ModelPessoa` em alguns cenários. Mas novamente, pode ser *overkill*.

[`Extension methods`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) podem ser usados para implementar estes padrões, ou algo próximo deles, de forma mais simples.

E outros padrões podem ser usado em conjunto de acordo com cada necessidade.

## Conclusão

Eu vejo maneiras de organizar melhor o código, prepará-lo melhor para a manutenção, mas vejo poucas chances de torná-lo menos repetitivo. Até porque não vi repetição ali. Pode ter me escapado alguma coisa. A repetição está mais no consumo da validação, não na validação em si.

Um [artigo que pode dar algumas ideias se precisar de uma solução complexa](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29777/steps-to-write-flexible-business-validation-in). Não gosto de tudo nela, mas ajuda entender o que pode ser feito.

## Exemplo prático

Note que este exemplo foi feito correndo, sem testar muito - tem vários erros, e não está nem de perto tentando mostrar a melhor forma. Apenas mostra uma forma possível, sem pensar muito em todas as consequências e necessidades. O exemplo pode ser usado para ter ideias, mas não como receita. De fato fiz um monte de coisa que pode ser desnecessário, fiz apenas para mostrar cenários diferentes.

Em código real certamente faria um pouco diferente. Em código de teste, simples, eu não faria nada disto. Este código foi feito para mostrar um meio termo entre um exemplo fictício e um exemplo de mundo real. Quando fazemos aplicações reais, certas lógicas não podem ser aplicadas. Eliminar repetição é ótimo, mas as coisas não são tão repetitivas assim. Quando generalizamos algo ser ter consciência do que estamos fazendo, cedo ou tarde vamos ter problemas.

O código é uma simplificação. Consigo imaginar uma lista enorme de melhorias, e já achei alguns *bugs*.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; } = "";
    public string Endereco { get; set; } = "";
    public int Idade { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Cargo { get; set; } = "";
    public decimal Salario { get; set; } = 0M;
}
public class ModelPessoa : Model<Pessoa> { //adotei a ideia que o Model seria para validar mesmo.
    override public bool Validate() {
        Required("Nome", Value.Nome);
        ValidaEndereco();
        Required("Cargo", Value.Cargo);
        Custom("Salário", "SalarioValido", "O Salário não atende os requisitos", ValidaSalario);
        Range("Idade", Value.Idade, Util.GetMaioridade(), 120);
        return (IsValid = Errors.Count == 0);
    }
    public int AsIdade(string texto) { //isto não é tão necessário, mas quis mostrar esta possibilidade
        var idade = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(texto, out idade)) {
            return idade;
        } else {
            Errors["IdadeInconsistente"] = new Invalidation("Idade", "A Idade foi digitada de forma inconsistente");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public decimal AsSalario(string texto) { //isto funciona como uma abstração/encapsulamento da funcionalidade
        var salario = 0M;
        if (decimal.TryParse(texto, out salario)) {
            return salario;
        } else {
            Errors["SalarioInconsistente"] = new Invalidation("Salario", "O Salário foi digitado de forma inconsistente");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    private void ValidaEndereco() { //tem a vantagem de que pode mudar a regra facilmente tendo um método isolando a funcionalidade
        if (!Util.IsStandardAddress(Value.Endereco)) {
            AddError("EnderecoPadrao", "Endereço", "EnderecoPadrao", "O Endereço está em formato inválido.");
        }
    }
    private bool ValidaSalario(object[] values) { //feito para operar com o Custom, pode mudar as regras fácil aqui de forma canônica
        return ((!Errors.ContainsKey("IdadeInconsistente") && Value.Idade > 21 && Value.Salario > 1000M)) ||
            (Value.Cargo != "Gerente" && Value.Salario > 900M) ||
            (Value.Cargo == "Gerente" && Value.Salario > 1200M);
    }
}
public static class Util { //esta classe foi só para agrupar, em código real estes métodos estariam em outras classes
    public static string Read(string label) {
        Write(label);
        return ReadLine();
    }
    public static int GetMaioridade() {
        return 18; //aqui poderia estar pegando de um banco de dados ou arquivo de configuração
    }
    public static bool IsStandardAddress(string address) {
        return address.Length > 2 && (address.Substring(0, 3) == "Rua" || address.Substring(0, 3) == "Av.");
    }
}
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        while (true) {
            var mp = new ModelPessoa(); //o modelo é usado para trabalhar com dados temporários
            mp.Messages["Idade"] = "A pessoa precisa ser maior de idade"; //personalizando uma mensagem
            mp.Value.Nome = Util.Read("Nome: "); //lê o dado e guarda no modelo
            mp.Value.Endereco = Util.Read("Endereço: ");
            mp.Value.Idade = mp.AsIdade(Util.Read("Idade: ")); //tentando converter
            mp.Value.Cargo = Util.Read("Cargo: ");
            mp.Value.Salario = mp.AsSalario(Util.Read("Salário: "));
            if (mp.Validate()) {
                Pessoa funcionario = mp.Value; //se está válido, então pode jogar em um objeto definitivo, gravar em DB, etc
                WriteLine("Cadastro efetuado!");
                break;
            } else {
                WriteLine("Erros ocorreram!");
                foreach(var erro in mp.Errors) { //tem várias formas para mostrar os erros
                    WriteLine(erro.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Invalidation { //uma classe simplificada para guardar dados completos sobre uma invalidade, parecido com exceção, sem ser
    public string Data { get; private set; }
    private string message;
    public string Message {
        get {
            return message ?? "Dado inválido";
        }
    }
    public Invalidation(string data, string message = null) {
        Data = data;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return Message;
    }
}
public abstract class Model<T> where T : new() { //mecanismo básico de validação separado do modelo em si. Tem maneiras mais simples de fazer o controle de erros
    public T Value { get; private set; } = new T();
    public bool IsValid { get; protected set; } = false;
    public Dictionary<string, Invalidation> Errors { get; protected set; } = new Dictionary<string, Invalidation>();
    public Dictionary<string, string> Messages { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public abstract bool Validate();
    protected void Required(string field, string value) { //alguns exemplos de códigos genéricos de validação
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
            AddError(field + "Required", field, "Required", "O campo {0} é obrigatório.");
        }
    }
    protected void Range(string field, int value, int min, int max) {
        if (value < min || value > max) {
            AddError(field + "Range", field, "Range", "O campo {0} deve estar na faixa de {1} até {2}.", min, max);
        }
    }
    protected void Custom(string field, string messageKey, string messageAlt, Func<object[], bool> condition, params object[] values) {
        if (!condition(values)) {
            if (values != null && values.Length > 0) {
                AddError(field + messageKey, field, messageKey, messageAlt, values?[0], values?[1], values?[2]); //está porco, mas não vou gastar tempo
            } else {
                AddError(field + messageKey, field, messageKey, messageAlt);
            }
        }
    }
    protected void AddError(string errorKey, string field, string messageKey, string defaultMessage, object value1 = null, object value2 = null, object value3 = null) {
        var message = "";
        Errors[errorKey] = new Invalidation(field, string.Format(Messages.TryGetValue(messageKey, out message) ? message : defaultMessage, field, value1, value2, value3));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PzuDRq). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Y6A4B). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Validation2.cs).

Se eu tiver tempo e o AP achar bom, posso ver se faço uma versão como *framework* usando atributos e automação e generalização de algumas tarefas. Não prometo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta bigown, irei estudar mais a fundo.

Comment: Depois você pode fazer perguntas mais específicas sobre isto. O assunto rende.

Comment: Irei implementar seu exemplo para ver como funciona e aprender mais a respeito, mas como vc mesmo disse as regras e a logica muda, as vezes depende do senário, porem seu exemplo ja é um grande passo, achei muito interessante como ficou seu exemplo, ainda tenho que termina de testa-lo, se quiser pode fazer uma versão como framework eu apoio a ideia, vai ajudar muita gente.

Comment: Na classe `Model` o que significa esta expressão: `Model<T> where T : new() ` ?

Comment: É meio complicado responder aqui no comentário, acho que caberia uma pergunta.

Comment: Irei elaborar uma :)

Answer (score 6):

De fato **tem muita repetição de código** aí e você tem razão em estar preocupado.

C# oferece ótimos recursos de orientação a objetos para favorecer a reutilização e evitar repetição de código.

> Você pode **generalizar o código, simplificando-o**.

As boas práticas na validação de campos começam com as boas práticas comuns a qualquer código C#, como por exemplo: promover a reutilização, dar preferência a código declarativo em vez de imperativo, reduzir a complexidade ciclomática...

## Generalizando para remover IFs e CASEs

Que tal se em vez de fazer isso para cada campo:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcionario.Nome))
{
    return 1 // código de erro;
}
```

Você pudesse fazer simplesmente isso:

```
ValidaCampoObrigatorio("Nome", funcionario.Nome, mensagem, errosValidacao);
```

E que tal se em vez de fazer isso para cada campo:

```
case 1:
    Console.WriteLine("Nome é obrigatório.");
    break;
```

Você pudesse fazer simplesmente isso:

```
Console.WriteLine(erro);
```

Será que ficaria melhor?

No código abaixo, eu generalizei a validação por tipo de validação e, em vez fazer um **if** para validar cada campo eu fiz apenas um **if** por *tipo de validação*.

Esta solução também dispensa os códigos de erro, substituindo-os por uma lista de erros de validação.

Como bônus, o **switch case** foi removido.

```
class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int Idade { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public double Salario { get; set; }
    public string Cargo { get; set; }
}

class ModelPessoa
{
    public List<string> ValidarCampos(Pessoa funcionario)
    {
        var errosValidacao = new List<String>();

        var msgCampoObrigatorio = "{0} é obrigatório.";

        CampoObrigatorio("Nome", funcionario.Nome, msgCampoObrigatorio, errosValidacao);
        CampoObrigatorio("Endereço", funcionario.Endereco, msgCampoObrigatorio, errosValidacao);
        CampoObrigatorio("Cargo", funcionario.Cargo, msgCampoObrigatorio, errosValidacao);
        ValorMinimo("Salário", 0.01, funcionario.Salario, "Salário deve conter valor acima de zero." , errosValidacao);
        ValorMinimo("Idade", 18, funcionario.Idade, "Funcionário tem que ser adulto.", errosValidacao);

        return errosValidacao;
    }
    private void ValorMinimo(string nomeCampo, double valorMinimo, double valor, string mensagemPattern, List<string> errosValidacao)
    {
        if (valor < valorMinimo)
            errosValidacao.Add(string.Format(mensagemPattern, nomeCampo, valorMinimo));
    }
    private void CampoObrigatorio(string nomeCampo, string valor, string mensagemPattern, List<string> errosValidacao)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(valor))
            errosValidacao.Add(string.Format(mensagemPattern, nomeCampo));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pessoa funcionario = new Pessoa();

        Console.Write("Nome: ");
        funcionario.Nome = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

        Console.Write("Endereço: ");
        funcionario.Endereco = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

        Console.Write("Cargo: ");
        funcionario.Cargo = Console.ReadLine().ToString();

        Console.Write("Salario: ");
        funcionario.Salario = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Idade: ");
        funcionario.Idade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var errosValidacao =  new ModelPessoa().ValidarCampos(funcionario);

        if (errosValidacao.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cadastrato com sucesso.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        foreach(var erro in errosValidacao) 
            Console.WriteLine(erro);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Outro benefício deste modelo de validação é que ela **apresenta os erros de de todos os campos de uma única vez**, em vez de ter que ensinar o usuário preencher um a um na base da "tentativa-e-erro".

Observe ainda que as funções de validação *CampoObrigatorio* e *ValorMinimo* **ficaram tão genéricas que na verdade podem ser usadas para validar qualquer entidade do seu sistema** e não apenas o funcionário!

Basta você movê-las para uma classe mais genérica e então a *ModelPessoa*, bem como o código de validação de qualquer entidade no sistema, passaria a consumir esta classe genérica de validação.

Você ainda pode retornar objetos como resultado da validação em vez de retornar apenas as mensagens, de modo que **você pode pôr no resultado da validação mais informações úteis**, como por exemplo a identificação do campo, de modo a poder marcá-lo na tela ou exibir a mensagem de validação junto dele se você estiver usando uma interface gráfica.

## Validações declarativas

Agora que você já generalizou as validações por tipo de validação em vez de escrever uma específica para cada campo, um próximo passo seria criar *Attributes* para declarar estas validações em cada propriedade da entidade em vez de ter que explicitamente invocar a validação para cada propriedade a ser validada.

Então, em vez de fazer assim para cada campo:

```
ValidaCampoObrigatorio("Nome", funcionario.Nome, mensagem, errosValidacao);
```

Você faria mais ou menos assim:

```
[Obrigatorio(mensagemPattern)]
public string Nome { get; set; }
[ValorMinimo(18, mensagemPattern)]
public int Idade { get; set; }
```

E o método *ModelPessoa.ValidarCampos* teria uma única linha, invocando esta validação baseada em *attributes*, a qual, naturalmente, também seria genérica para qualquer tipo de entidade do sistema:

```
public List<string> ValidarCampos(Pessoa funcionario)
{
    return new ValidacaoEntidade(mensagensPattern).Valida(funcionario);
}
```

É lógico que neste caso provavelmente a classe *ModelPessoa* devesse desaparecer e o método de validação estaria na própria entidade.

Você provavelmente também vai querer usar um arquivo *resources* para as mensagens de erro em vez de deixá-las *hardcoded*; não para a necessidade de criar traduções para o sistema porque pode ser que você nunca precise, mas sim para facilitar a programação, simplificar o código e centralizar as mensagens do sistema, facilitando a alteração e reutilização.

## Exemplo de validações declarativas

Ao usar *attributes* para declarar a validação de cada campo, eu matei a sua classe *ModelPessoa* pois a única função dela era validar a entidade *Pessoa*, e agora esta função fica com **a classe *ValidacaoEntidade*, que é capaz de validar qualquer entidade do sistema e não apenas pessoas**.

```
interface IValidacaoAttribute
{
    string Mensagem { get; }
    bool Valido(object valor);
}

class ObrigatorioAttribute : Attribute, IValidacaoAttribute
{
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }

    public bool Valido(object valor)
    {
        return valor != null && !((valor as string) == "");
    }
}

class ValorMinimoAttribute : Attribute, IValidacaoAttribute
{
    public double Minimo { get; set; }
    public string Mensagem { get; set; }

    public bool Valido(object valor)
    {
        return valor != null 
            && (double)Convert.ChangeType(valor, typeof(double)) >= Minimo;
    }
}

class ValidacaoEntidade
{
    public static List<string> Valida<T>(T entidade)
    {
        var errosValidacao = new List<string>();
        var propriedades = typeof(T).GetProperties()
            .Where(prop => prop.IsDefined(typeof(IValidacaoAttribute), false));

        foreach (var propriedade in propriedades)
        {
            var validacoes = (IValidacaoAttribute[])propriedade
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IValidacaoAttribute), false);
            foreach (var validacao in validacoes)
            {
                if (!validacao.Valido(propriedade.GetValue(entidade)))
                    errosValidacao.Add(string.Format(validacao.Mensagem));
            }
        }
        return errosValidacao;
    }
}

class Pessoa
{
    [Obrigatorio(Mensagem = "Nome é obrigatório.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Obrigatorio(Mensagem = "Endereço é obrigatório.")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [Obrigatorio(Mensagem = "Cargo é obrigatório.")]
    public string Cargo { get; set; }

    [ValorMinimo(Minimo = 18, Mensagem = "Funcionário tem que ser adulto")]
    public int Idade { get; set; }

    [Obrigatorio(Mensagem = "Salário é obrigatório.")]
    [ValorMinimo(Minimo = 0.01, Mensagem = "Salário deve conter valor acima de zero.")]
    public double? Salario { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Pessoa funcionario = new Pessoa();

        Console.Write("Nome: ");
        funcionario.Nome = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Endereço: ");
        funcionario.Endereco = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Cargo: ");
        funcionario.Cargo = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Salario: ");
        double salario;
        funcionario.Salario =
            double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out salario) ? (double?)salario : null;

        Console.Write("Idade: ");
        funcionario.Idade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var errosValidacao = ValidacaoEntidade.Valida<Pessoa>(funcionario);

        if (errosValidacao.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cadastrato com sucesso.");
            return;
        }
        foreach (var erro in errosValidacao)
            Console.WriteLine(erro);
    }
}
```

Observe que **cada campo pode ter mais de um tipo de validação** (no campo *Salário* eu usei duas validações).

Para **validações mais complexas onde não caiba usar *attributes***, você poderia fazer suas entidades implementarem uma interface com um método *Validar* e chamar esté método durante a validação da entidade. Dentro deste método você poderia escrever qualquer código de validação e adicionar mensagens à lista de erros de validação.

Embora eu considere a implementação do validador baseado em *attributes* bastante simples, veja que não importa a complexidade dele pois **um dos grandes benefícios é justamente afastar a complexidade de validação da lógica de negócio e de aplicativo**.

É claro que este exemplo é baseado apenas na necessidade que você expôs. Na prática, você vai precisar de muitos outros tipos de validação; **e aqui vemos mais uma vantagem do estilo declarativo: para cada novo tipo de validação, você só precisa implementar uma nova classe atributo** (nos mesmos moldes que *Obrigatorio* e *ValorMinimo*) e declarar estas validações em qualquer propriedade que desejar, de qualquer entidade. **Não terá que mexer em nehuma classe existente**.

Você pode implementar cada uma delas por conta própria, como eu demonstrei aqui em dois exemplos, e pode também usar **frameworks** para lhe poupar serviço (geralmente as bibliotecas de validação são usadas em associação com frameworks ORM).

## Conclusão

Você pode melhorar o seu código simplesmente criando funções para **generalizar validações** que já são conceitualmente genéricas. E generalizar código é uma prática importante em qualquer área do sistema, não apenas nas validações.

Você pode ir mais além, criando *attributes* para **declarar as validações** em vez de escrevê-las de maneira imperativa para cada entidade do sistema.

Você pode também usar **frameworks** que já tenham implementado padrões de validação que sirvam ao seu projeto.

<sub>E caso você opte por um framework, o bacana é que, se você assimilou esta resposta, você já saberá em parte como eles funcionam em vez de só enxergar mágica, e esse tipo de conhecimento pode lhe ajudar de diversas maneiras.</sub>

Comment: Se tiver interesse em um exemplo funcional usando *attributes* é só deixar um comment.

Comment: Vou estudar mais a sua resposta e implementar sua solução, e sim tenho interesse no exemplo usando attributes, se tiver algo a mais há acrescentar.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Tá lá, postei o código usando attributes.

Comment: Implementei os dois exemplos seu, porem me surgiu mais algumas duvidas vou vê se faço mais perguntas, obrigado pela ajuda :) +++++1.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos melhorar a leitura do seu código então, vamos ignorar os números inteiros e passar a usar enumeradores, como o que fiz abaixo:

```
public enum ResultadoValidacao : int
{
    nomeNulo = 1,
    enderecoNulo = 2,
    cargoNulo = 4,
    salarioInvalido = 8,
    menorDeIdade = 16,
    tudoOk = 32  // se estiver tudo beleza
};

public ResultadoValidacao InvaValidarCampos(Pessoa funcionario) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcionario.Nome)) //Verifica se há conteúdo na variável.
        return ResultadoValidacao.nomeNulo;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcionario.Endereco)) //Verifica se há conteúdo na variável.
        return ResultadoValidacao.enderecoNulo;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(funcionario.Cargo)) //Verifica se há conteúdo na variável.
        return ResultadoValidacao.cargoNulo;
    if (funcionario.Salario <= 0) //Verifica se o valor do salário é valido.
        return ResultadoValidacao.salarioInvalido;
    if (funcionario.Idade < 18) //Verifica se o funcionário é maior de idade.
        return ResultadoValidacao.menorDeIdade;

    /* você pode usar números também, como por exemplo, menorDeIdade = 16 */
    return ResultadoValidacao.tudoOk; //Todos os campos atende os requisitos das regras.
}
```

Agora vamos simplificar essa parte do código implementando a função `EscreverEObter`; declare esse método:

```
string EscreverEObter(string oQuePedir)
{
    Console.Write("\n" + oQuePedir);
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

E vamos usar esse método no seu código:

```
Pessoa funcionario = new Pessoa();
ModelPessoa mp = new ModelPessoa();

funcionario.Nome = EscreverEObter(@"Nome: ");
funcionario.Endereco = EscreverEObter(@"Endereço: ");
funcionario.Cargo= EscreverEObter(@"Cargo: ");
funcionario.Salario = EscreverEObter(@"Salário: ");
funcionario.Idade = EscreverEObter(@"Idade: ");

//Tem duas variáveis que tem que ser apenas numéricas, vamos ver se o usuário
//digitou um número válido nela.
if (!Decimal.TryParse(funcionário.Salario, null)) { //Decimal por que o salário é um decimal
    Console.WriteLine("Salário inválido.");
}
if (!UInt16.TryParse(funcionário.Idade, null)) { //Idade é um número inteiro
    Console.WriteLine("Idade inválida.");
}

switch (mp.ValidarCampos(funcionario)) 
{
    case ResultadoValidacao.nomeNulo:
        Console.WriteLine("Nome é obrigatório.");
        break;
    case ResultadoValidacao.enderecoNulo:
        Console.WriteLine("Endereço é obrigatório");
        break;
    case ResultadoValidacao.cargoNulo:
        Console.WriteLine("Cargo é obrigatório.");
        break;
    case ResultadoValidacao.salarioInvalido:
        Console.WriteLine("Salario deve conter valor acima de zero.");
        break;
    case ResultadoValidacao.menorDeIdade:
        Console.WriteLine("Funcionário tem que ser adulto.");
        break;
    default: 
        Console.WriteLine("Cadastrado com sucesso."); 
        break;
}
```

Existem muitas maneiras de simplificar seu código, uma delas é usando expressões regulares para validar um texto.

Comment: Obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento.

Comment: O  `case ResultadoValidacao.cargoNulo:` não funcionou, tive que trocar por `case ValidacaoCampo.Pessoa.ResultadoValidacao.NomeNulo:` porque o Compilador pediu e não aceitou. PS: ValidacaoCampo é o namespace do meu exemplo.