# Criação de métodos para validação em C #

Tags: c#

Como posso criar uma classe e um método que sejam universais para validação de TextBox para formulários no C#.
Por exemplo, preciso criar um método que valide um campo denominado Nome em meu formulário de cadastro de cliente para que esse campo não fique vazio ou nulo
Fiz alguns códigos que validaram o que eu queria,  porém, tive que duplicar este código em vários formulários, tornando minha manutenção e gerenciamento trabalhosos 
Alguém poderia me ajudar a criar este método?

Desde já eu agradeço.

Eduardo

Comment: Da uma olhada nessas [respostas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105670/27190).

Comment: qual foi a duplicata??