# O que é Strategy pattern?

Tags: design-pattern, independente-de-linguagem, strategy-pattern

Estava lendo a respeito do [Strategy pattern](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy), porém, não consegui entender ele muito bem e fiquei confuso em relação ao seu funcionamento.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é o Strategy pattern?
2. Em quais cenários eu devo utilizá-lo?

<sup>De preferência eu gostaria de exemplos na linguagem C# ou PHP se possível. Mas sinta-se à vontade para dar exemplos em qualquer linguagem.</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> O que é o Strategy pattern?

Ocorre quando um objeto pode ter maneiras diferentes de se comportar com relação a um aspecto específico dele.

Ele se confunde muito com outros ou é usado junto com outros padrões. Ele é muito parecido com o [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), que já é muito parecido com o [Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) e acaba servindo como [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Ele também lembra o [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) e até o [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Até mesmo o State é parecido e frequentemente confundido. Outros possuem características semelhantes. Não estou dizendo que fazem a mesma coisa, mas todos servem para agregar alguma coisa a um objeto sem precisar mexer no próprio. Boa parte dos padrões mudam por pequenos detalhes, o que pode tornar difícil escolher o mais adequado.

A maneira tradicional de lidar com isso é ter um parâmetro (fixo como parte da estrutura de um objeto ou circunstancial só recebido pelo comportamento (método) e tomar uma decisão de qual código executar baseado nele. Todos os códigos estão intimamente ligados ao objeto e a seleção de qual executar costuma ser feita por um `switch`.

Isso tem algumas desvantagens:

- a classe ou método passar ter [várias responsabilidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101)
- precisa ter os fontes para acrescentar ou modificar uma nova estratégia
- se adicionar uma estratégia nova pode criar problemas com herança e outras formas de composição de métodos para este tipo
- a adição de nova estratégia provavelmente exigirá vários pontos independentes de manutenção.

É comum ter uma classe de seleção de contexto, que faz a administração da escolha da estratégia. Isto é útil porque mantém a estratégia desacoplada do objeto que precisa consumi-la.

Há quem use uma [Factory](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101) para escolher a estratégia que será aplicada. Nos exemplos ali acabam implementando uma forma de SP. A fábrica pode substituir o que se chama de contexto.

A maioria dos artigos que ensinam os padrões são um pouco acadêmicos usando termos abstratos para cada coisa e nem sempre é fácil ligar esses termos como o uso real.

[image: Strategy pattern]

> Em quais cenários eu devo utilizá-lo?

Acho que isso está definido acima, vou partir para alguns exemplos reais.

Um deles pode ser visto em uma [pergunta de um sujeito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105670/101) aí :P

[Outro exemplo](http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern) existe no site sobre o GoF.

Na minha humilde opinião o exemplo em Java da página da Wikipedia *linkada* na pergunta é ruim ou até está errado. O fato de juntar tudo em um local só perde a capacidade de criar novas estratégias de forma independente. Se for para fazer isso eu prefiro a solução mais simples de ter ou uma classe única que cuida de tudo ou funções independentes sem classes.

#### *Logs*

Pense em uma aplicação que precisa gerar *logs* de atividades e a forma de decidir onde e como *logar* entre arquivo, mail, MySQL, e quem sabe depois possa ter syslog, SQLite, etc. O padrão é usado para decidir o que usar.

## Impostos

Um exemplo típico poderia ser o cálculo de imposto da comercialização de um produto. É certo que o produto só deveria lidar apenas com coisas que dizem respeito diretamente a ele. Porém calcular o imposto de comercialização dele é algo relacionado a ele. Cada unidade federativa tem uma maneira diferente de calcular o imposto, seja pela fórmula, seja pela alíquota ou base de cálculo diferente, além de tratar exceções diferentes.

A melhor solução é permitir que o cálculo seja determinado externamente. Cria-se um classe abstrata base ou interface para este cálculo e cada estado deriva dela para implementar o cálculo da sua forma. A classe do produto só precisa saber que existe o cálculo, qual é ele será determinado pelo contexto da utilização do objeto.

Se o produto está sendo comercializado em São Paulo, chamará o método de cálculo e possivelmente outros desta classe, se a operação ocorre em outro estado usará outra classe com o mesmo contrato.

Se um dia criarem um estado novo, é só criar uma classe nova, se tiver outras formas novas que não sejam dependentes do estado é possível adicioná-las sem mudar nada em código algum, só adicionar a nova estratégia de cálculo.

```cs
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var calc = new CalculaImposto(new CalculaImpostoSP());
        WriteLine("Imposto SP: " + calc.Calcula(1500M)); //aqui obviamente pegaria o valor do produto na classe específica
        calc.Strategy = new CalculaImpostoRJ();
        WriteLine("Imposto RJ: " + calc.Calcula(1500M));
    }
}

public interface ICalculaImposto {
    decimal Calcula(decimal baseCalculo);
}

public class CalculaImpostoSP : ICalculaImposto {
    public decimal Calcula(decimal baseCalculo) => baseCalculo * 0.18M;
}

public class CalculaImpostoRJ : ICalculaImposto {
    public decimal Calcula(decimal baseCalculo) => baseCalculo * 0.12M;
}

public class CalculaImposto {
    public ICalculaImposto Strategy { get; set; } //constuma-se considerar isto obrigatório para cumprir o padrão
    public CalculaImposto(ICalculaImposto strategy) { Strategy = strategy; }
    public decimal Calcula(decimal baseCalculo) => Strategy.Calcula(baseCalculo);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/O1S6k1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oL5uYq). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/StrategyImposto.cs).

## *Lambda*

Embora oficialmente ele seja planejado para usar com classes e orientação a objeto, ele pode ser aplicado mais ou menos igual sem esta característica. O uso de delegados ou *lambdas* servem muito a esse propósito, ainda que alguns não considerem o uso deste mecanismo o mesmo que fazer o Strategy Pattern.

Pensa bem, se você tem um código que sabe o que fazer, mas precisa ter várias estratégias diferentes que você pode querer, mandar um método com a forma é a mesma coisa que o padrão da estratégia faz. Desde que o método mandado para este algoritmo tenha o contrato desejado, ou seja, recebe os argumentos que serão mandado para ele e retorna o que se espera dele, ele é uma estratégia adequada.

Por isso tem programador que abuse dele e cria uma solução complexa para resolver um problema simples.

Answer (score 6):

O `strategy pattern` é útil quando você tem várias formas de realizar determinada tarefa. A intenção dele é separar componentes com uma finalidade igual, contudo esses componentes funcionam de forma diferente.

Um exemplo fácil de entender é tentar fazer validação a uma string. Você quer aplicar regras de validação a uma string, por exemplo:

> Tem tamanho máximo de 100 caracteres.
> Não pode começar por um numero.
>
> Só pode conter números e letras.

Se você implementar estas regras sem o `strategy pattern` o código fica mais ou menos assim:

```cs
var value = "A string para eu validar";
var isValid = value.Length <= 100
    && !char.IsDigit(value[0]) 
    && value..All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))

if(!isValid){
  throw new InvalidOperationException("A string não é válida");
}
```

Se você aplicar o `strategy pattern` você implementa uma classe para cada regra de validação. É claro estas classes tem que ter alguma flexibilidade, por exemplo um dia pode querer validar strings de 80 caracteres, então é boa ideia desenhar a sua classe  que valida o tamanho para suportar qualquer tamanho. Aqui está o mesmo exemplo aplicando o `strategy pattern`

```cs
public IValidator{
    bool IsValida(string value);
}

public class StringMaximumSizeValidator : IValidator{

    private int _size;
    
    publiic StringMaximumSizeValidator (inte size){
        _size = size;
    } 

    public bool IsValid(string value){
        return value != null && value.Length <= _size;
    }
}

public class StringIsNotDigitValidator : IValidator{
    private int _idx;
    
    publiic StringIsNotDigitValidator (int idx){
        _idx = idx;
    } 

    public bool IsValid(string value){
        return value != null && !char.IsDigit(value[_idx]);
    }
}

public class StringAlphanumericValidator : IValidator{
    public bool IsValid(string value){
        return value != null && value..All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
    }
}

    
var value = "A string para eu validar";
var validators = new IValidator[]{
    new StringMaximumSizeValidator(100),
    new StringIsNotDigitValidator(0), 
    new StringAlphanumericValidator()
};
var isValid = validators.All(v => v.IsValid(value));

if(!isValid){
  throw new InvalidOperationException("A string não é válida");
}
```

A vantagem é que agora as regras de validação são feitas através de um objeto. Isto permite testar melhor cada um dos processos de validação.
Também deverá ser mais fácil criar novas regras de validação e usar aquelas que quer para um determinado cenário.