# Em Java, qual o propósito de chamar métodos da interface em objetos de outras classes?

Tags: java, design-pattern, interface

Segue o código que estou estudando:

```
public interface Node {
    public abstract int eval ();
}

public abstract class Unary implements Node {
    private final Node child;

    public Unary(final Node child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    public final int eval () {
        return compute(child.eval());
    }
    protected abstract int compute(int c);
}

public abstract class Binary implements Node {
    private final Node left;
    private final Node right;

    public Binary(final Node left, final Node right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public final int eval() {
        return compute(left.eval(), right.eval());  // minha dúvida aqui, porque left.eval() 
                                                    // ao invés de só left?
    }

    protected abstract int compute(int l, int r);
}
```

A minha dúvida é, para a classe `Binary`, no método `eval ()` quando retorna `compute(left.eval(), right.eval())`, porque as variáveis `left` e `right` são seguidas pelo método `eval()` da interface? visto que os métodos de interface não fazem nada.

Comment: Eles "não fazem nada" na interface `Node`. Mas, se você passar um objeto que implementa a interface `Node`, e cria uma implementação para o método `eval`, ele retornará (ou deverá retornar) um inteiro.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2913/112052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Padrão de projeto

Isso tem cara de ser um padrão de projeto, não garanto exatamente qual porque alguns são parecidos e nem sempre são implementados certos (parece com um [Strategy](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187908/101)). Mesmo que não seja nenhum dos mais conhecidos ainda é um que tem um propósito. Parece usar mais de um *design pattern*.

Essa forma de abstração permite a flexibilidade de trabalhar com objetos que são nós sem se preocupar com detalhes de como o nós lhe darão a informação sobre eles que um algoritmo precise. A única coisa que você precisa saber sobre os nós é que ele tem um método `eval()` que te dá a informação necessária.

As implementações concretas de `Node` terão um código nesse `eval()` que diz que informação é relevante para identificar o que ele representa, mas o que especificamente é só vendo o código de cada um (estamos vendo duas quase implementações, pelo menos o método está implementado, mas como não são classes concretas ainda não serão nessas classes que serão usados de fato).

Quando chama o método e cada um dos campos do objeto está só pegando essa informação. Só se sabe que ela devolverá um valor inteiro.

E podemos observar que ele será usado em um método que não sabe nada sobre esses nós, ele poderia receber qualquer coisa, e que apenas em classes concretas terá exatamente como deve computar isso.

## Interface

O objetivo da interface é justamente dar um contrato, uma forma que um objeto terá se decidir se conformar com ela, então todo mundo que receber um objeto dessa interface poderá fazer aquilo, e só aquilo, que a interface disse que que ele é capaz.

Note que os campos `child`, `left` e `right` são do tipo da interface, podem conter objetos de qualquer tipo que as implemente, ele não liga para o resto do que esse objeto é ou faz, só para o que a interface determinou.

Answer (score 1):

O método `eval()` (que significa *evaluate*, ou seja, avaliar) da interface `Node` realmente não faz nada porque é só um contrato. Ele está lá para obrigar quem implementa essa interface a implementar esse método.

Porém as classes `Unary` e `Binary` que estão implementando essa interface são abstratas (`abstract`). Isso quer dizer que elas não são obrigadas a implementar esse método, e delegam essa tarefa para quem for subclasse concreta (não-abstrata) dessas classes.

Então se você tiver `class Concreta extends Binary { ... }`, por exemplo, ela vai ser obrigada a implementar `eval()`.