# Como se utilizar propriedade expandida no C#

Tags: c#, .net, propriedade

Estou com um problema, criei uma classe contendo a seguinte propriedade:

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
public int Idade {get; set;}
}
```

Porém, quando eu faço isso:

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
   public int Idade {
      get{
         return Idade;
      }
      set{
         if (value < 18)
            throw new Exception("Proibido para menores!");
         else
            Idade = value;
      }
   }
}
```

O código acima não funciona e sou obrigado a criar um atributo private para armazenar o valor `idade`, ou pelo menos tenho feito assim. Isso está correto? Por que não posso usar `Idade = value`?

```
public class MinhaClasse
    {
       private int _idade;
       public int Idade {
          get{
             return _idade;
          }
          set{
             if (value < 18)
                throw new Exception("Proibido para menores!");
             else
                _idade = value;
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: tenta public int idade(int idade)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem que criar o campo privado para funcionar, você está criando um *loop* infinito, porque está usado a propriedade `Idade` para manipular a propriedade `Idade`, o que então forçará manipular `Idade` e assim vai.

```
using System;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var obj = new MinhaClasse();
        obj.Idade = 20;
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Idade);
        obj.Idade = 10;
        
    }
}

public class MinhaClasse {
    private int idade;
    public int Idade {
        get => idade;
        set => idade = value < 18 ? throw new Exception("Proibido para menores!") : value;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mtSDCo). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jD3YhO). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/Mechanism.cs).

Sempre que lança uma `Exception` está fazendo algo errado. Até consideram que esta classe deveria ser abstrata para ninguém poder usar. Muitas pessoas consideram ruim lançar exceção em uma propriedade, pelo menos em boa parte dos casos. Isto é [controlar fluxo com exceção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101).

Comment: Por que no primeiro exemplo que dei o código funciona e não cai no loop?

Comment: Porque você não está manipulando a própria propriedade, em algum lugar daquele código mostra que está fazendo isso?

Comment: Por causa do Set.

Comment: Não entendi....

Comment: Me ajude a compreender uma coisa, no primeiro exemplo, ele cria um atributo para a classe com o mesmo nome da propriedade?

Comment: Não, ele cria um campo com o nome que ele quiser.

Comment: Daí, a partir do segundo exemplo, ele já não cria mais esse campo e a propriedade se comporta como um método, por isso eu tenho que criar um campo eu mesmo. É isso?

Comment: Sim, sempre é um método, ou dois se fizer as duas operações. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101

Comment: Para situações como a do segundo exemplo, poderia existir algo como um "return value" (ou algo assim) dentro do set. Deste modo ele não cairia em loop e saberia que era para definir o valor da propriedade. Assim eu não precisaria criar um campo chamado idade só para isso e código ficaria mais limpo. Por isso fiz a pergunta, achei que o C# tinha algo desse tipo para resolver o problema.

Comment: Não, o `set` é `void`. Ambos caem em *loop* se você usar o próprio nome, e nada que não seja usar outro nome pode resolver isso, menos ainda um `return`.

Comment: Mas quando faço uso apenas do `public int Idade {get; set;}` ele entende sozinho que é para retornar o valor da propriedade e "setá-la". Quando digo `Idade=value` ele poderia entender que não quero um loop infinito e sim fazer o set da propriedade.

Comment: Sim............

Comment: Quem viu algum problema na resposta favor informar para eu arrumar. Ou tirar o negativo sem motivo.

Comment: Não fui eu, eu dei até um positivo para equilibrar novamente. A resposta me foi muito útil.

Comment: @Maniero o uso de Dataannotations não seria mais apropriado para validar a lógica do modelo?

Comment: @gato Depende de várias cosias, tem usos que não serve pra nada, porque precisa de um *framework*  que faça a validação, tem casos que ela não resolve, tem casos que não faz sentido usá-la, afinal é uma forma declarativa, e boa parte dos código precisam ser imperativos, o declarativo é bom quando vai usar em algum outro lugar e o *framework* específico precisa entender a semântica daquilo. De forma geral não sou muito fã

Comment: @Maniero hum entendi. Lembrei me [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105684/27190), acho que o AP pode dar uma olhada e aprender um pouco sobre validação ;D

Comment: É, ali foi criado um *framework* :) Não gosto pra tudo.