# Como atribuir uma data padrão em um objeto tipo DateTime no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, getters-setters

Criei uma classe chamada `Order`, e nela criei um *field* com o propósito de inserir uma data de entrega da *order*.

Porém criei o objeto no `Main()`, e na hora que executo ele preenche com a data *default*, já fiz o *debug* mas não sei onde estou errando.

Essa é minha classe `Order`:

```
namespace SergioS_301011342_LIB
{
    public class Order
    {
        private DateTime orderDateMade;
        private DateTime orderDateDeli;
        private AddressStruct orderAddressDeli;
        private decimal cost;
        private Customer customer;
        private static int orderNumber;
        private OrderItem[] orderItems;
        private int noOrders;
        private const uint MAX_NUMBER_OF_ORDERS = 50;

        public Order()
        {
            orderItems = new OrderItem[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ORDERS];
            noOrders = 0;
            orderNumber += 1;
            orderDateDeli = new DateTime();
        }

        public Customer Customer
        {
            get { return customer; }
            set { customer = value; }
        }

        public OrderItem[] OrderItems
        {
            get { return orderItems; }
            set { orderItems = value; }
        }

        public int OrderId
        {
            get { return orderNumber; }
        }

        public DateTime OrderDateMade
        {
            get { return orderDateMade; }
            set { orderDateMade = DateTime.Now; }

        }
        public DateTime OrderDateDeli
         {
          get { return orderDateDeli; }
            set { orderDateMade = DateTime.Today; }

        }
        public AddressStruct OrderAddressDeli
        {
            get { return orderAddressDeli; }
            set {orderAddressDeli = value; }
        }
        public decimal Cost
        {
            get { return cost; }
            set { cost = value; }
        }
        public void AddOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
        {
            orderItems[noOrders++] = orderItem;//verify if the array is not full before save it.
            Cost += orderItem.MenuItem.MenuBaseCost;

        }


        public string GetInfo()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            result += "\n\t\t\t\t\tId Order : " + orderNumber + "\n";
            result += "========================================================================================";
            result += "\nDate of the order: " + this.OrderDateMade.ToString();
            result += "\t\tDate of the delivery: " + orderDateDeli.ToString();

            result += "\nDelivery Address: " + this.orderAddressDeli.streetNumber + ", ";
            result += this.orderAddressDeli.streetName + ", " + this.orderAddressDeli.city + "-";
            result += this.orderAddressDeli.province + "\n";

            result += "Orders: \n";
            foreach (OrderItem item in this.orderItems)
            {
                if (item == null)break;
                result += item.GetInfo();
            }
            result += "\n========================================================================================";
            result += "\nCost total of the order: " + this.Cost.ToString("C2");
            result += "\n========================================================================================";
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

Esse é o `Main`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SergioS_301011342_LIB;


namespace SergioS_301011342_A1
  {
    class Program
    {
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem(new MenuItem()
            {
                MenuName = "Hot Coffee",
                MenuDescription = "Dark Coffee with 2 milks and 2 creams",
                MenuBaseCost = 3.5M,
            });
            OrderItem orderItem2 = new OrderItem(new MenuItem()
            {
                MenuName = "Milk",
                MenuDescription = "Hot Milk",
                MenuBaseCost = 2.5M,
            });


            Customer customer1 = new Customer();
            customer1.Name = "Richard Silva";
            customer1.PhoneNumber = "6471231212";

            var address = new AddressStruct()
            {
                streetNumber = 1600,
                streetName = "Progress Avenue",
                city = "Toronto",
                province = "ON",
            };
            customer1.Address = address;


            var addressDelivery = new AddressStruct()
            {
                streetNumber = 890,
                streetName = "Keele Street",
                city = "Toronto",
                province = "ON",
            };
            var order = new Order();
            order.OrderAddressDeli = addressDelivery;
            order.AddOrderItem(orderItem);order.OrderItems[0] = orderItem;
            order.AddOrderItem(orderItem2);order.OrderItems[1] = orderItem2;
            customer1.Orders[0] = order;

            order.OrderDateMade = new DateTime();
            order.OrderDateDeli = new DateTime();


            Console.WriteLine(customer1.GetInfo());

            Console.ReadLine();


        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você não usar o `value` de alguma forma isso não é um *setter*.

Na verdade o código original está cheio de problemas conceituais.

Nem vou comentar o nome do *namespace* `SergioS_301011342_LIB`, ele só me dá medo :)

Me parece que [o construtor está sendo usado de forma equivocada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Em primeiro lugar o que está ali deveriam ser propriedades inicializadas, mas o mais provável é que deveria realmente ter um construtor com os dados obrigatórios do objeto. Desta forma o objeto nem faz sentido existir porque ele pode ser criado de forma inválida. Parece que vale para todos os construtores.

E está permitindo inicialização de coisas que são muito fáceis de cometer erros, deveria ter um outro controle sobre a inicialização de quase tudo, especialmente estes textos soltos, isto não pode estar certo.

Parece que os *getters* e *setters* existem porque foi seguida receita de bolo. Já se questionou se precisa mesmo? Se deve ser assim? Pesquise aqui no site, tem muita informação sobre o abuso deles.

Pegar `OrderItens` parece [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101).

Idealmente deveria usar só as propriedades auto implementadas. Veja mais abaixo *links* sobre o assunto.

A forma como está construindo o texto é bastante inadequada. Veja [O que significa o sinal de arroba "@" no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41166/101) e [O que significa o simbolo "$" antes de uma string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101), e principalmente [Por que devo usar a classe StringBuilder ao invés da classe String?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101).

Aí você tem que se perguntar, o pedido quando criado pode ter sua data mudada? Se não puder, deve fazer algo assim:

```
public DateTime OrderDateDeli { get; } = DateTime.Today;
```

Se puder ser mudado, isto pode ser feito de forma indiscriminada? Provavelmente não, aí seria algo assim:

```
public DateTime OrderDateDeli {
    get => orderDateDeli;
    set {
        //faz aqui o tratamento necessário com o value para poder usar corretamente
    }
}
```

E aí agora você precisa fazer a inicialização no construtor, não tem jeito, o facilitador só existe quando a propriedade é auto implementada. É só fazer `orderDateDeli = DateTime.Today;` no construtor.

Somente se não tiver restrição que pode fazer assim (mas sem restrição parece errado):

```
public DateTime OrderDateDeli { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/DefaultInField.cs).

Desconfie de alguém pedir para não usar a auto implementada quando ela é a adequada, isso ensina nada. Usar uma implementada onde precisa ensina corretamente a mesma coisa que fazer manual o que pode ser auto implementada.

Veja mais:

- [Métodos e propriedades em C# - vantagens e desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15467/101)
- [Propriedade Vs variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101)
- [Como se utilizar propriedade expandida no C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/263498/101)
- [Campo público X propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324099/101)
- [Inicialização estranha de propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126348/101)
- [Como funcionam as propriedades no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156804/101)
- [Nova funcionalidade do C# 6 "Auto-property initializers" é apenas um facilitador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108516/101)

Answer (score 3):

```
public DateTime OrderDateDeli
{
    get { return orderDateDeli; }
    set { orderDateMade = DateTime.Today; } // está orderDateMade em vez de orderDateDeli
}
```

> A partir do C # 3.0, foi implementada o recurso das propriedades
>   auto-implementadas.
>
> Através das propriedades auto-implementadas podemos fazer a declaração
>   das propriedades de uma classe de uma maneira mais concisa quando
>   nenhuma lógica adicional é necessária nos assessores (get e set) das
>   propriedades.

Fonte: [macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/11/05/c_pai.htm)

Exemplo:

```
public DateTime OrderDateDeli { get; set; }
```

> No C# 6 e versões posteriores, é possível inicializar as propriedades
>   autoimplementadas da mesma forma que os campos:

```
public DateTime OrderDateDeli { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: Entendi, mas o meu professor e tão chato ( ao ponto de dar um teste para ser feito no no NotePad ao inves do Visual Studio) então ele proibiu o uso de propriedades autoimplementadas. Disse que depois que aprender como e feito, poderemos usar a autoimplementada.