# É errado colocar essa quantidade de código em um evento de click de botão?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, estilo-de-codificação

É errado colocar essa quantidade de código em um evento de *click* de botão?

```
private void CPeBTNSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (CPeTBCodigo.Text == "")
            {
                throw new ExcecaoModificada("Determine um codigo para o pedido!");
            }

            int codigo = int.Parse(CPeTBCodigo.Text);
            int ano = CpeData.Value.Year;
            int mes = CpeData.Value.Month;
            int dia = CpeData.Value.Day;
            bool semPedido = true;

            Pedido p = new Pedido(codigo, ano, mes, dia);

            foreach (DataGridViewRow x in dG_CPeListarProdutos.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(x.Cells[4].Value) > 0)
                {
                    ItemPedido item = new ItemPedido(FormularioPrincipal.lProduto[x.Index], Convert.ToInt32(x.Cells[4].Value), Convert.ToDouble(x.Cells[3].Value));
                    p.itens.Add(item);
                    semPedido = false;
                    x.Cells[3].Value = 0;

                    x.Cells[4].Value = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    x.Cells[3].Value = 0;
                }
            }
            if (semPedido == true)
            {
                throw new ExcecaoModificada("Escolha algum produto!");
            }
            else
            {
                CPeLabelAlerta.Visible = true;
                CPeLabelAlerta.Text = "Novo pedido adicionado!";
                CPeLabelAlerta.ForeColor = Color.DarkSlateGray;
                FormularioPrincipal.lPedido.Add(p);
            }
        }
        catch (ExcecaoModificada erro)
        {
            CPeLabelAlerta.Visible = true;
            CPeLabelAlerta.Text = erro.Message;
            CPeLabelAlerta.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            CPeLabelAlerta.Visible = true;
            CPeLabelAlerta.Text = "Coloque apenas numeros em código!";
        }
    }
```

Se você acha que não é errado, cite algo que não faria como eu fiz.

Comment: Normalmente eu criaria uma função e só chamaria no evento do botão, além de facilitar a chamada em outros eventos deixaria o código mais visualmente organizado :)

Comment: Acho que não há necessidades de ficar lançando exceções assim. Da uma olhada [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions). Certamente que você esta usando o recurso de forma errada.

Comment: Se uma função tem muito código, provavelmente, ela pode ser dividida em funções menores, por exemplo, uma função separada que valida um determinado dado

Comment: Obrigado gente! @gato vou estudar mais do assunto vlw :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deveria ter só o código mais óbvio que deve executar quando o botão é clicado.

Uma parte do código parece não ter a ver com com o acionamento do botão em si, e por isso deveria ser delegado para outros métodos, como validação e preparação de outras partes da tela. Depende muito também do resto do código para avaliar. Em geral eles serão privados ou até mesmo pertencentes a outra classe (no caso da validação em si que é regra de negócio e não regra de tela).

Na verdade parece ter erros bem mais importantes neste código, como o `Pedido` que é bem esquisito, a forma de conversão de dados é propensa a erros, o uso de exceções está errado em todos os sentido. Só não é fácil arrumar sem conhecer totalmente o problema. O problema parece ser estrutural, e por isso não daria para arrumar só esse detalhe, teria que consertar toda a aplicação.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Acho que você escreveu exatamente o que eu precisava, vou rever tudo que você citou!

Answer (score 1):

Há muita redundância no seu código. O evento `CPeBTNSalvar_Click` vai solicitar o registro de algo no banco ou arquivo? Parece que ele esta só buscando os dados do `DataGridView` e adicionando na sua classe, e como o @Maniero disse, deveria ter apenas o código necessário. Deixe os nomes mais claros e legíveis também, só use prefixo se tiver algum beneficio que vale a pena.

## Validação dos dados numéricos

No seu código basta um método para fazer a validação

```
if (int.TryParse(CPeTBCodigo.Text, out var resultado)){ ... }
```

Não precisa validar mais de uma vez como `CPeTBCodigo.Text == ""` e `int.Parse(CPeTBCodigo.Text);`, como esta em seu código.

## Exceções

Pode aprender o básico de como [usar exceções aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions), sempre tente evita-las. Exceções desnecessárias podem atrapalhar na hora de rastrear algum erro ou prejudicar a performance da aplicação. E no seu caso você usa exceções para tratar dados que vem do usuário, não há necessidades de criar exceções para isso.

## Regras de negócio

No entanto, se você quiser pode usar o [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) para definir os meta dados para o controle dos dados mantidos no objeto. Em seguida você um `ValidationContext` para descrever o contexto da validação e `ValidationResult` para obter o resultado da validação e as mensagens de erro.

#### Pequeno exemplo de ilustração

O exemplo abaixo ilustra como usar os recursos citados acima, veja:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; // Tem que adicionar esta referencia ao seu projeto.

public class Produto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo é obrigatório.")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    
    [Range(1.0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Oops... o preço não pode ser 0 (zero) ou menor.")]
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }
    
    
    public void Validate()
    {
        Produto produto = this;
        ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(produto, null, null);
        IList<ValidationResult> erros = new List<ValidationResult>();
        
        if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(cliente, context, erros, true))
        {
            foreach (ValidationResult resultado in erros)
            {
                MinhaListaDeErros.Add(resultado.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }    
        
        if (!MinhaOutraValidacao()) MinhaListaDeErros.Add("Minha outra mensagem de erro.");
    }    
}
```

O exemplo acima é para mostrar um caminho, tem muita coisa que deve ser melhorado, portanto, seja cuidadoso, e considere o contexto e a necessidade da sua aplicação.

Aprenda mais sobre [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj129537.aspx).

Mais sobre [validação de campos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/105684/27190).

Comment: Muito obrigado por dar mais detalhes, estou revendo todos os meus pontos fracos. Vou estudar sobre DataAnnotations.

Comment: O evento pega os produtos do DataGrid que foram selecionados e os adicionam numa lista