# Dúvida visibilidade dos atributos no diagrama de classe

Tags: modelagem, uml, visibilidade

Recentemente tivemos uma discussão em sala sobre a questão da visibilidade dos atributos no diagrama de classes. Alguns afirmaram que no diagrama (assim como no código) todos os atributos devem ser privados. Entretanto, o professor fez a seguinte observação: no diagrama de classes, representamos a visibilidade da PROPRIEDADE do atributo. Segue um exemplo (puramente didático):

```
    private string _CPF;

    **public** string CPF {
        get { return _CPF; }
        private set
        {
            if (value.Length == 11)
                _CPF = value;
        }
    }
```

Neste caso acima, segundo ele, o correto seria colocar o atributo (no diagrama) como público (devido a propriedade ser pública (em negrito)). Entretanto, neste caso, o `get` é público e o `set` privado, portanto, como represento a visibilidade do atributo `_CPF` no diagrama de classe?

Todos os materiais que já li falam pra colocar todos os atributos no diagrama privados, portanto devo usar todos como privados ou devo colocar a visibilidade da propriedade?

Comment: Acredito que isto seja uma peculiaridade do C# (é a utilizada na pergunta, certo?) que permite a definição de propriedades. Isto é, você pode fazer `cpf = obj.CPF`, como se tivesse acessando um atributo diretamente, mas na verdade é o método `get` que será executado. Desta forma, a propriedade `CPF` atua (por assim dizer) como um atributo público e indicar o atributo `_CPF` como privado seria redundância. Linguagens que não suportam isso, como o PHP, o atributo deveria ser posto no diagrama como privado e seus métodos `get` e `set` como públicos.

Comment: Obrigada Anderson, esclareceu muito boa parte das minhas dúvidas! Abraço.

Comment: Não coloquei como resposta porque acho que não tenho autoridade para responder com clareza a pergunta, principalmente em C#. Se ninguém responder (descentemente), eu elaboro uma resposta (se é que o que eu disse faz sentido).

Comment: @T.Borges da uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75265/propriedade-x-atributo) para aprender a respeito de atributo x propriedade. Se a propriedade é publica você pode deixar ela publica no seu diagrama de classe, lembrando que uma propriedade pode ser publica mais somente leitura em alguns casos.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que se você deseja que sua propriedade seja acessada publicamente, no diagrama deve ser marcado como `public`. Como boas práticas, o `set` deve sempre ser `private` (ou `protected` se utilizar herança). Tendo o `set` como `private`, você garante que alguma regra de negócio seja executada antes de *setar* a propriedade, evitando erro de validação.

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/118043)

Comment: Obrigado @diego. Sou novo aqui. Tentei ajudar. Abs

Answer (score -1):

Um diagrama de classes é uma abstração de como as coisas vão ser implementadas. A quantidade de detalhes depende da ferramenta utilizada e nem sempre (na verdade quase nunca) representa fielmente como o código será realmente construído.

Dito isso: dada uma equipe de X pessoas que irá trabalhar sobre um diagrama com Y classes, a quantidade de interpretações diferentes para o mesmo diagrama terá a mesma ordem que X<sup>y</sup> (antes de cortarmos as redundâncias). Só pelo que você disse eu já consegui pensar em quatro possibilidades:

- Seu professor entende que todos os atributos são privados, e que as lógicas internas das classes não devem ser representadas. O diagrama deve conter somente propriedades, que são públicas por definição;
- Seu professor entende que todos os atributos devem ser representados como privados, e todas as propriedades como públicas;
- Idem acima, porém com notação de somente-leitura para a propriedade;
- Seu professor só quer provocar uma discussão e ver o consenso a que a turma chega.

Então eu tenho dois conselhos:

**1-)** Assim como os alunos e usuários do SO têm visões diferentes sobre o problema, diferentes professores podem dar diferentes respostas também. Como o professor é a autoridade na sala de aula, ele tem o voto de Minerva sobre o que é certo. Consulte ele, e não o SO, para saber qual resposta é a **correta para a sua sala de aula.**

**2-)** Não se preocupe muito sobre qual resposta é a mais pedantemente correta nesse caso, pois mais adiante você verá que um diagrama de classes está para o código fonte correspondente como isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está para isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]