# Conceito de classe, entidade e objetos

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos

Estou lendo sobre classes em C#, e um trecho me deixou um pouco confuso.

Sei que classes são objetos em C#, e podem ser utilizadas de várias formas.

Minha dúvida é na seguinte frase:

"Uma classe pode ter tanto os atributos quanto métodos de uma entidade do sistema"

A classe em si, seria considerada uma entidade do sistema ou não? Se sim, acredito que a frase acima teria que ser diferente.

Quando falamos de entidades, podemos nos referir somente a classe ou a qualquer objeto?

Comment: Viu isso em algum livro, na web não existe nada nem parecido com isso.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Sei que classes são objetos em C#, e podem ser utilizadas de várias formas.

[Classe não é um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101). Classe é um modelo a ser seguido, objeto usa esse modelo para se estruturar.

Pense em tempo de desenvolvimento e tempo de execução. Classe é definida no primeiro, o objeto no segundo. Classe só existe no seu código, objeto só existe quando a aplicação está rodando. É uma simplificação, mas assim é fácil entender.

Comparando com banco de dados, a estrutura definida para uma tabela é a classe, cada linha dessa tabela é o objeto.

> A classe em si, seria considerada uma entidade do sistema ou não? Se sim, acredito que a frase acima teria que ser diferente.

Sim, uma classe é um modelo de entidade do sistema. Não vejo porque deveria ser diferente. Do ponto de vista de arquitetura a classe é um modelo que representa uma entidade. Arquitetura só existe no papel, a concretização dela é que gerará objetos. Os objetos funcionam como entidades. Exemplo: a classe diz como os dados de um cliente devem ser organizados, mas um cliente só existirá de fato em objetos.

Assim como tabelas em DBs são entidades, classes são entidades na modelagem. Separe da sua mente o modelo do dado real.

Só tome cuidado porque em linguagens de programação *mainstream* onde lê atributo, entenda como campos, ou mesmo propriedades, já que [o termo é usado para outra coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101).

> Quando falamos de entidades, podemos nos referir somente a classe ou a qualquer objeto?

A entidade em si é o objeto. A classe é um tipo de uma entidade, ou em outras palavras, é uma classe de objeto. Classe vem de classificação, vem de generalização de um grupo de objetos com as mesmas características. A classe é uma abstração da entidade. Quando estamos falando da abstração, usamos o termo entidade, mas na verdade aquilo é um tipo de entidade.

Pense em um mapa. Apontamos para a cidade tal. Estamos apontando para uma abstração que representa a cidade naquela tela, mas ela não é a cidade. A cidade é uma entidade. No mapa tratamos aquela representação como se fosse uma entidade. O termo pode ser usado nos dois contextos, mas o mais correto seria dizer "representação da cidade no mapa". O importante é que se você fala só "cidade" em um mapa, todo mundo entende que aquilo é só uma representação.

#### Uma nota filosófica

Tecnicamente o objeto da aplicação também não é a entidade, apenas usamos o termo assim para facilitar. A entidade mesmo só existe no mundo real. Então um cliente é o cliente mesmo, é uma pessoa ou uma empresa. O objeto na sua aplicação funciona como uma figura representativa. Para sua aplicação o mundo real não existe. [Tron](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084827/) só existe na ficção.

[image: Cena de Tron]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: no seu post você disse o seguinte: "Classe tipifica o que será modelado por ela. Ela determina os estados possíveis e os comportamentos que os objetos podem ter.". Entendo que a partir de uma classe são criados objetos. Se os objetos são gerados a partir das classes. As classes são considerados o que ? Ainda não ficou claro. Pode explicar melhor

Comment: @DiegoFarias estava sem tempo ontem, dei uma melhorada na resposta. Acho que a resposta que eu *linkei* dá um exemplo bem claro.

Comment: Ok, vou ler e qualquer dúvida aviso ou posto uma nova pergunta. Obrigado

Comment: Ficou mais claro, porém, essa questão de abstração confunde minha cabeça. Como estou lendo bastante sobre esses assuntos, acredito que jajá essa confusão desapareça.

Comment: Se eu tenho uma classe dicionário e cadastro uma palavra com seu significado, essa palavra com seu significado é um objeto, e este é único. Essa classe foi abstraída, neste caso, a partir de uma ideia? A ideia de reunir várias palavras com seus significados (dicionário)? Se dicionário é uma entidade, a entidade não existe somente no mundo real. E abstrair seria o que exatamente? Seria fazer uma análise de algo real ou então de uma ideia? Ainda estou achando confuso: classe, objeto e entidade. Eu achava que entidade era uma classe.

Comment: Quando é formulado um diagrama de entidade e relacionamento, você cria uma entidade, por exemplo entidade Pessoa, esta não seria uma classe? Porque você disse que entidade é o objeto e não a classe.

Comment: Você vê uma pessoa, esta é uma entidade do mundo real, então você faz uma abstração (análise) dessa pessoa e cria uma classificação para ela, que seria uma classe, é isso? E no caso do dicionário antes dele mesmo existir, fazemos a sua formulação na nossa mente, é uma ideia, representamos essa ideia numa classe Dicionário, mas se fosse para elaborar um diagrama de entidades, Dicionário não seria uma entidade?

Comment: O dicionário é um objeto, a palavra é um objeto menor que estará dentro deste objeto maior, dicionário é um *container*. É uma abstração. Abstrair, neste contexto, é fazer uma representação no seu código, é criar algo que diz como é a entidade real. Você está no caminho certo. Dentro do seu código a entidade é uma classe, mas só no seu código, porque a entidade física no mundo real não pode estar dentro do seu código. A **classe é uma representação da entidade**, o seu erro talvez esteja aí, ela não é classe. Em geral até falamos assim como simplificação, mas não é o conceito correto.

Comment: Uma pessoa em específico é um objeto, a ideia de pessoa é uma classe. A entidade é a pessoa, no computador será um objeto, a representação de uma entidade que seja classificada como pessoa, no computador será uma classe. Você não analisa uma pessoa, mas sim como é pessoas no geral. Uma pessoa pode ser usada como base para enxergar mais facilmente como uma pessoa é composta, como se comporta. No diagrama podemos dizer que ele é um entidade porque um diagrama já é uma representação (um desenho para você visualizar "essa ideia") ...

Comment: ... quando você fala que é um entidade é como se você estivesse vendo o ecossistema real pronto, ali "no papel" é apenas um modelo, e no código você diz como é o modelo por uma classe (em linguagens que tem classes, claro), é pra você pensar naquilo como se já fosse o objeto, por isso que se fala que é uma entidade. É fácil você saber que aquilo não é um objeto, ele não tem dados, está dizendo que tem um nome, mas não diz que é o "João". Só o objeto tem o "João", a classe é abstrato demais, você só sabe que há uma característica nome naquele possível objeto.

Comment: Classe é uma generalização ou classificação de um objeto. Objeto é algo específico. Isso eu compreendo. Mas ficou confuso a parte da entidade, pois você disse que a classe é uma representação da entidade, disse que a entidade é uma classe dentro do código, porém disse também que a entidade pode ser uma pessoa e no computador será um objeto. A entidade é tanto a classe quanto o objeto?

Comment: É, depende do ponto de vista, no momento do desenvolvimento é a classe, na execução é o objeto, mas na vida real é o que gerou isso no computador. Faz uma coisa, esquece entidade :) É conceitual demais e é algo que está causando confusão. Tira da equação e entenda o que é importante.

Answer (score 1):

Resumo da obra:

> 1. **Classe** é um conjunto de objetos distintos, porém com as mesmas características e comportamentos.
> 2. **Objeto** é uma instância ou modelo derivado de uma classe. Portanto objeto é a representação de qualquer coisa, real ou abstrata, do mundo real que irá ser manipulado ou armazenado pelo sistema.