# Pra que usar VAR em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, variáveis

Pra que usar VAR em php se ja conseguimos declarar variáveis sem VAR?

Podemos fazer isso: `$teste` então, pra que fazer isso? `var $teste`

Por exemplo, é a mesma coisa eu fazer isso?

```
class Caneta {
    var $modelo;
    var $cor;
}
```

E isso:

```
class Caneta {
     $modelo;
     $cor;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> Não use `var` para declarar propriedades de classes isso era usado no php4.

A palavra chave `var` era usada no php4 para definir uma propriedade em uma classe. A partir do php5 seu uso foi desaconselhado em lugar deve-se utilizar algum dos modificadores de acesso: `public`, `protected` ou `private`.

No exemplo de código é a mesma coisa ambas propriedades serão acessiveis por todos ou seja equivale ao `public`. Por padrão se o modificador de acesso for omitido sua visibilidade será `public` isso vale para métodos também.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Propriedade x Atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/91)

Comment: Olha minha edição, rray, por favor? :)

Comment: @LucasCarvalho complementei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado rray, só resumindo, fica a mesma coisa usar qualquer um dos 2? No caso no PHP5

Comment: @LucasCarvalho fica a mesma coisa, o ideal é não usar `var` mesmo. No manual cita que da versão 5.0 até a 5.1.2 era gerado um warning depois não mais. [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: rray, sabe por que que no NetBeans fica dando erro se eu não usar var?

Comment: Olha? http://prntscr.com/fhu95j

Comment: @LucasCarvalho é aviso que você deveria utilizar algum modificar de acesso. Ele sugere que é mais legível utilizar algum mas nesse caso não é gerado nenhum erro, se não me engano você pode desligar algumas regras da checagem de código do netbeans.