# Como remover o aviso de não utilizar VAR no NetBeans?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, netbeans

Aqui mesmo no SO, vi que não preciso mais utilizar VAR, ao declarar uma variável em PHP, isso era somente até o PHP4. O NetBeans, fica dando erro, se eu não usar, e usar somente a variável

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como removo isso?

Comment: Não conheço muito de PHP, mas acho que você está declarando atributos de classe, não variáveis. Não sei se isso tem diferença na linguagem. Pelo erro, parece que é necessário um modificador de acesso antes de `$modelo;`, não?!

Comment: Mas a partir do php5 não precisa mais usar o ´var $nomedavariavel´ é só usar o $nomedavariavel

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi da [resposta que você aceitou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/211655/4808), é necessário um modificador de acesso, não diz nada sobre não usar **nada** antes do nome do atributo.

Comment: É o que o Renan falou, pra remover o aviso tem dois caminho, usar um IDE que não avise :), o que não recomendo, ou consertar o problema no código.

Comment: Eu que tinha entendido errado.

Comment: Tome cuidado **variável** e **atributo/propriedade** são coisas diferentes, se notar nenhum comentário ou resposta citou variável.

Comment: Obrigado rray, to me confundindo um pouco nessa entrada em POO, mas vou estudando.

Comment: Só lembrando que aprender a sintaxe Orientada a Objetos, não faz você programar orientado a objetos (e não há nada de errado nisso). Se você programa em paradigma estruturado, recomendo que permaneça um tempo ainda programando nesse paradigma, mesmo usando sintaxe orientada a objetos (por uma questão de comunidade, não possível explicar por aqui). Os casos de usos aonde aproveitará o paradigma orientado a objetos aparecerá com naturalidade. Não caia no papo do "programador de verdade faz isso...." ou "aquilo...". Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para declarar um atributo dentro de uma classe no PHP, você declara a visibilidade, depois o atributo.

**Certo**

```
<?php
    Class MinhaClasse{
public $atributo;
}
```

**Errado**

```
    Class MinhaClasse{
$atributo;
}
```

Comment: Tem no caso que declarar então se ela é uma variável publica, privada ou trancada ne?

Comment: Dentro de classe sim

Comment: Obrigado, Paulo!