# Diferença entre sintaxe de propriedades no C#

Tags: c#, .net, sintaxe, propriedade, visibilidade

Pelo que pesquisei, se eu fizer:

```
public int numero { get; set; }
```

é a mesma coisa que:

```
private int numero;

public int Numero {
    get{
        return numero;
    }

    set{
        numero = value;
    }
}
```

Mas no primeiro trecho de código tudo fica com acesso `public`, já no segundo o atributo é declarado como *private* e o `get` e `set` são `public`, isso não tem realmente diferença?

Comment: Nesse sentido não porque o que pode ser acedido de forma pública é exactamente o mesmo nos dois casos - a propriedade `Numero`

Comment: Pelo que explica no link abaixo não é atributo e sim características de um objeto.(Ou variável de classe ou de instância)
Recomendo a leitura: [Propriedade x Atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75265/propriedade-x-atributo)

Comment: Tambem não entendo bem a diferença então tenho a mesma duvida

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa como em java ?

private String name; 
public void setName(String name) { 
this.name=name; 
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação, os trechos são (praticamente) equivalentes. No segundo, você define um campo da classe como privado e cria uma propriedade para gerenciá-lo.

```
public class Person
{

    // Define o campo `name`:
    private string name;

    // Define a propriedade `Name`:
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Ou seja, desta forma você está criando um campo `name` privado e uma propriedade `Name` pública que acessa o campo `name`. Mas se nenhuma lógica for necessária na implementação dos acessadores do campo, `get`e `set`, não há a necessidade de escrever todo esse código acima. A partir da versão 3.0 do C# é possível fazer apenas:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; };
}
```

Com esta sintaxe, o C# criará a propriedade `Name` definindo os métodos `get` e `set` assim como no exemplo acima, porém, também criará um campo privado e anônimo para suporte que será acessado por tais métodos. Vide [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties):

> Ao declarar uma propriedade o compilador cria um campo de suporte privado e anônimo que pode ser acessado somente por meio dos acessadores `get` e `set` da propriedade.

Esta sintaxe é denominada propriedade autoimplementada. Uma leitura interessante sobre o assunto é:

[Propriedade Vs Variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/5878)

Na verdade, esta é até duplicata desta pergunta.

**Documentação**

[Usando propriedades (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

[Propriedades autoimplementadas (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

Answer (score 6):

O primeiro código é um açúcar sintático para o segundo, grosso modo. Então não há diferença entre eles, isto você sabe. Se é a mesma coisa, por que a dúvida? O primeiro tem tudo o que tem no segundo, você só não está vendo escrito ali.

Se escrever o primeiro é o mesmo que tivesse escrito o segundo, é óbvio que não tem diferença. Você talvez esteja querendo ver outra coisa que não existe aí.

Existe um campo privado no primeiro também, afinal onde ele vai guardar o dado? Precisa ser em uma variável da classe (estática ou de instância, no caso é de instância). Só porque você não digitou ou não vê não quer dizer que não esteja lá.

O código do `get` e do `set` são métodos que executam um código, por mais simples que eles sejam, mas não armazenam valores, só o campo pode armazenar um valor. Ambos são públicos.

Aliás, muita gente acha que uma linha de código pode ser mais rápida que várias linhas. Isto obviamente não é verdade, o que está por trás daquela linha é que define o que ela faz. O que você vê é sempre uma abstração de algo maior. Na verdade, nem mesmo uma linha de Assembly define oi quanto custa um processamento, cada instrução seu custo diferente.

Veja como fica o código gerado:

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never), CompilerGenerated]
private int <numero>k__BackingField; //o campo privado criado pelo copilador

private int _numero; //o cam criado manualamente

public int numero
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return this.<numero>k__BackingField; //o acesso criado pelo compilador
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    set
    {
        this.<numero>k__BackingField = value; //a mutação criada pelo compilador
    }
}

public int Numero
{
    get
    {
        return this._numero;
    }
    set
    {
        this._numero = value;
    }
}
```

[Veja no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoGYECY4DCcA3hnOQjgJYB2ALnDQK4C2ApgE4D2JcA5mzrI4AZ0HIAvmQoAHDlQBuAQzps4tBgH1m7bmnQVK6+nAByrTl1IGKAhtcOGAkFADscbRb3THcKTfIxex9HJ09dHgBeOGUAGyY2fV9yf0N/CSA=).

Comment: Não se pode fazer assim tambem? private int _numero; 
public void setName(int _numero) { 
this._numero=_numero; 
}

Comment: Pode, mas isso não é C# idiomático, tem desvantagens.

Comment: ok então, entendi

Comment: Ia perguntar sobre a diferença de definir uma propriedade assim e manter o campo como público, mas pesquisei e acabei achando esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133924/propriedade-vs-vari%c3%a1veis). No fim, acho que é até duplicata.

Answer (score 1):

Concordo que é um açúcar sintático. Na prática (pra mim, ok?) eu uso o get;set; sem nada quando só preciso atribuir a propriedade "as is". Quando é necessário fazer algum tipo de tratamento (como formatar a saída, por exemplo) eu declaro os fields privados e os trato nos métodos get e set. Eu faço isso só para poder padronizar as interações com a propriedade sem ter de alterar um zilhão de classes prováveis.

Fora isso, não tem diferença de performance, etc. Vc só escreve um pouco mais.

Espero ter ajudado!