# Significado dessas nomenclaturas em Python e em outras linguagens, se os nomes que forem universais

Tags: python, convenções-de-nome

Gostaria de saber o significado com exemplos, se necessário, dos seguintes nomes:

- Classe
- Objeto
- Atributo
- Método

Comment: [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/5878) | [Significado da terminologia: “Orientado a objeto”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/5878) | [Qual a diferença entre uma classe e um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/5878) | [Propriedade x Atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/5878)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os significados desses termos são universais em ciência da computação.
Eventualmente alguma linguagem pode ter outros significados para
alguns deles, mas ainda é "permitido" usa-los dentro da forma original.

O exemplo será só em Python.

Eu gosto de dar exemplos como o abaixo, com um "alô mundo" de um jogo 2D, por que ele tem exemplos de objetos que podem ser "vistos" na tela de forma bem concreta. Na prática, a maior parte dos objetos não tem uma correspondência com algo que é vísivel diretamente na tela. (eu falo de outros exemplos ao final)

## Classe

Há várias formas de escrever a definição do que é uma classe. Eu gosto de pensar em classes como um *objeto* que agrega *métodos* e dados (os *atributos*)  que funcionam como um conjunto independente dentro da sua modelagem de sistema.

Assim, por exemplo, num joguinho de tiro de naves, uma classe to dipo "NaveInimiga" pode conter os atributos de "velocidade", "direcao", "posicao_na_tela". E os métodos de "movimentar", "atirar" que são chamados como "ações" na execução do programa.

## Objeto

Uma "entidade" no seu sistema que agrega todos os dados que precisa para se auto definir, e as operações que podem ser feitas com esses dados.
Em linguagens que tem declaração explícita de classes (o caso do Python), em geral cada objeto é uma "instância" de uma classe: ou seja, ele agrega os mesmos métodos e atributos que outros objetos da mesma classe, mas os *atributos* são independentes entre si.

No exemplo do jogo de naves, uma nave pode estar na tela na posição (0,0) e ter a cor vermelha. Uma outra nave pode estar na tela na posição (200,0) e ter a cor azul. As duas vão compartilhar os mesmos métodos, e os tipos de atributos - mas os dados de cada uma - os *atributos* são separados.

## Atributo

É um valor associado a um objeto. Se voce sabe programar, conhece variáveis - os atributos são "variáveis atreladas a objetos específicos".
Ao falar de objetos, mencionei alguns atributos que as "naves" podem ter.

## Método

Se você ja programa, conhece o conceito de função: um bloco de código limitado, que vai trabalhar com dados passados para ela, podendo ou não causar um efeito fora desses atributos (imprimir algo no terminal, gravar um dado num arquivo, desenhar algo na tela), e retornar um valor.

Um método é um bloco de código muito parecido com uma função, mas é declarado em uma classe, e, quando é chamado, está vínculado a um objeto específico (uma instância da classe). Em Python inclusive são declarados da mesma forma as funções e os métodos. A maior diferença conceitual é que um método pode trabalhar com os *atributos* do objeto, sem precisar que todos os dados que vai usar sejam passados como parâmetros.

Por exemplo, a classe "nave" pode ter um método "movimentar", que, com base nos atributos de "velocidade" do próprio objeto, atualiza os atributos de "posicao'.

## Específico de Python

Python difere de algumas outras linguagens por que os atributos dos objetos de uma classe não são declarados na classe, em geral - mas sim, criados dinâmicamente quando um novo objeto é criado. Quando isso acontece, a linguagem chama automaticamente o método com o nome especial `__init__`. Em todos os métodos, o Python inclui automaticamente um primeiro parâmetro, que por convenção chamamos de "self": esse parâmetro é uma referência para o próprio objeto. A partir daí, usando o "." como separador, podemos associar atributos ao nosso objeto.

Abaixo, segue o exemplo de uma classe "nave" que poderia ser usada num joguinho. Depois segue a mesma classe, com comentários antes de cada linha descrevendo tudo.Para ficar menos abstrato, incluo um programa minimamente funcional (só precisa instalar o pygame junto com o Python):

```
import pygame

largura = 800
altura = 600
jogo_terminou = None


class Nave:
    def __init__(self, posicao, velocidade, cor):
        self.posicao = list(posicao)
        self.velocidade = velocidade
        self.cor = cor

    def movimentar(self):
        global jogo_terminou
        self.posicao[0] += self.velocidade[0]
        self.posicao[1] += self.velocidade[1]
        if self.posicao[0] > largura or self.posicao[1] > altura:
             jogo_terminou = True

    def desenha(self, tela):
         pygame.draw.rect(tela, self.cor, (self.posicao[0], self.posicao[1], 50, 50))


def principal():
    global jogo_terminou

    tela = pygame.display.set_mode((largura, altura))
    jogo_terminou = False

    nave1 = Nave(posicao=(0, 0), velocidade=(10, 5), cor=(255,0,0))
    nave2 = Nave(posicao=(largura, 0), velocidade=(-10, 10), cor=(0,0,255))

    while not jogo_terminou:
        nave1.movimentar()
        nave2.movimentar()

        tela.fill((0,0,0))

        nave1.desenha(tela)
        nave2.desenha(tela)

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.delay(100)

    pygame.quit()


principal()
```

Agora, o mesmo código com comentários sobre o que está sendo feito em cada linha, inclusive explicando o que é específico do Pygame:

```
# importa o módulo pygame, que disponibiliza funcionalidade
# para criar uma janela e desenhar na mesma
import pygame


# algumas variáveis globais que usamos no programa.
largura = 800
altura = 600
jogo_terminou = None


# Abaixo, declaração da classe Nave

class Nave:

    # Método inicializador: é chamado quando o Python
    # cria uma "instância", ou seja "um objeto" da classe
    # Nave. Os parâmetros passados parar criar o objeto
    # são repassados para o método __init__ - junto com
    # o "self" que é inserido automaticamente.

    def __init__(self, posicao, velocidade, cor):
        # Para cada parâmetro passado,
        # cria o _atributo_ correspondente
        # neste objeto:
        self.posicao = list(posicao)   # o atributo é convertido para "lista" para
                                       # que os componentes x e y possam ser atualizados
                                       # separadamente.
        self.velocidade = velocidade
        self.cor = cor

    def movimentar(self):
        # variável global - não é um atributo do objeto
        # o objeto usa para sinalizar que o jogo deve ser encerrado.
        global jogo_terminou

        # Atualizam o atributo "posicao"
        self.posicao[0] += self.velocidade[0]
        self.posicao[1] += self.velocidade[1]

        # Regra para verificar se o jogo terminou.
        # no caso desse exemplo, assim que uma nave saí
        # para fora da área do jogo em algumas direções específicas:

        if self.posicao[0] > largura or self.posicao[1] > altura:
             jogo_terminou = True

    # Método que recebe um parâmetro externo ao objeto
    def desenha(self, tela):
        # chama uma função na biblioteca para desenhar um retângulo
        # na posição indicada pelos atributos da própria nave;
        pygame.draw.rect(tela, self.cor, (self.posicao[0], self.posicao[1], 50, 50))


def principal():

    global jogo_terminou

    # chama o pygame para criar uma janela onde o jogo se desenrola:
    tela = pygame.display.set_mode((largura, altura))
    # note que essa função do Pygame também retornar um "objeto".
    # no caso é um objeto do tipo "Surface", que corresponde
    # à janela do jogo, que também tem métodos e atributos
    # que podemos usar.

    jogo_terminou = False

    # cria um objeto do tipo nave, com uma posicao, velocidae e cores definidas
    nave1 = Nave(posicao=(0, 0), velocidade=(10, 5), cor=(255,0,0))

    # A posicao e velocidade são passadas como uma sequência numérica de dois numeros,
    # onde o primeiro corresponde à coordenada horizontal, e o segundo à coordenad vertical.
    # Num exemplo maior, poderiamos criar uma classe específica "vetor" para
    # passar esses dados.

    # Já as cores são passadas como uma sequência de três números entre 0 e 255,
    # correspondendo ao vermelho, verde e azul da cor. Essa é uma convenção
    # do pygame, que faz muito sentido quando trabalhamos com imagens

    # cria _outro_ objeto do tipo nave, em outra posição, etc...
    nave2 = Nave(posicao=(largura, 0), velocidade=(-10, 10), cor=(0,0,255))

    # laço principal do jogo -
    # num jogo completo, aqui entraria o código
    # para verificar teclas oressionadas,
    # movimentação do mouse, etc....
    while not jogo_terminou:

        # chama o método movimentar de cada uma das naves.
        nave1.movimentar()
        nave2.movimentar()

        # chama o método do objeto da classe "Surface" do pygame que
        # preenche toda a área com uma única cor (no caso, preto)
        tela.fill((0,0,0))

        # Chama os métodos para cada nave desenhar a si mesma na tela.
        nave1.desenha(tela)
        nave2.desenha(tela)

        # Uma função especial do pygame que sincroniza o que se vê na janela
        # com o que foi atualizado na memória, com as chamadas acima.
        pygame.display.flip()
        # Uma função do pygame para fazer uma pausa de 100 milisegundos
        # antes de repetir as atualizações das naves.
        pygame.time.delay(100)

    # Funçao do pygame para encerrar a janela e outros objetos internos
    pygame.quit()

# chama a nossa funçao principal, que coordena todo o programa:
principal()
```

Esse código funciona e vai mostrar as naves, desenhadas como retângulos, se movendo na tela ao mesmo tempo, e se encerrando quando uma delas saí do campo de visão. Para executa-lo, no seu Python 3 instale o pygame (www.pygame.org)  - se estiver com o "pip" funcionando, basta digitar `pip install pygame`. Caso contrário, no Linux, algo como `sudo apt-get install python3-pygame`, para Windows, acredito que deva haver algum instalador no site.

---

Voltando a vaca fria, outros exemplos de objetos,, em outro contexto, poderiam ser uma conta bancária, que teria como atributos "saldo", "cpf_do_titular" e "limite" por exemplo.

A terminologia forma de orientação a objetos acrescenta outros termos formais, e a coisa pode parecer complexa  - você vai ver termos como "encapsulamento", "mensagens", etc..., mas os que você perguntou são os que tem uma representação bem concreta em código Python e estão exemplificados acima.  Alguns desses conceitos podem ser abstratos, e são mais fáceis de entender, ao meu ver, depois que se tem uma noção mais concreta como a que tento passar neste exemplo. E em particular aqui deixamos de fora o conceito de "herança", que alguns livros e textos gostam de apresentar de uma só vez.

Comment: Acredito que este tópico seja o mais próximo do ideal para levantar minha dúvida (mas se julgar que não é possível responder aqui), considerarei abrir uma pergunta específica. No vídeo [*The art of subclassing*](https://youtu.be/miGolgp9xq8?t=20m36s), do Raymond Hettinger, ele coloca que o Python tem sua implementação um tanto quanto diferente do *conceito* definido pelo OOP; que em Python, classes são consideradas dicionários de funções e que estaria *correto* criar subclasses apenas para reutilizar código, não para definir uma especialização apenas. Isso mudaria algo em sua definição?

Comment: No *slide* que citei no link, ele inclusive define o contraste entre a *operational view* e a *conceitual view*. É bem comum vermos em quase todos os materiais, mesmo em Python, abordar as definições da *conceitual view*, mas pela implementação do Python de seguir mais para o lado da *operational view*, não seria correto dizer que o OO do Python *foge um pouco*, por assim dizer, das definições conceituais da OO em si?

Comment: Bom, nçao sei se deixo transparecer o suficiente no último parágrafo, mas eu não curto muito um academiscismo, que considero exagerado em torno de algumas coisas (e olha que teve lugar onde trabalhei onde eu fui considerado "o academico chato"). Vou precisar ver os slides e essas definições pra responder mais propriamente. 
Mas em Python, uma coisa é certa: "praticidade bate o purismo".  

Acho que vale a pena perguntas separadas sim.

Answer (score 2):

**Classe**

Estrutura que contem comportamentos e características (métodos e atributos). ([Ler mais](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWzL-j3vPXAhUHkJAKHVHHA3QQFgg3MAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpt.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FClasse_(programa%25C3%25A7%25C3%25A3o)&usg=AOvVaw10iH_fFx0U583CeF-2Hfvq))

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade

    def get_info(self):
        return "%s tem %s anos" % (self.nome, self.idade)
```

**Objeto**

Objeto é o que recebe a instancia de uma classe. Veja no caso abaixo, instanciando a classe **criada anteriormente** e atribuindo ao `p1`. Essa variável p1 vai herdar todos os atributos e métodos da classe.

```
...
p1 = Pessoa("Guilherme", 21)
p1.get_info()
```

**Atributo**

Os atributos da classe são as variáveis criadas dentro das Classes. (Exemplo **Classe**) ([Ler mais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atributo_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)))

```
 self.nome = nome
 self.idade = idade
```

**Método**

Os métodos, são as funções dentro de uma classe que também são herdadas pelos objetos, quando instanciadas. (**Classe**). ([Ler mais](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwja2LL33vPXAhVKDpAKHfzaD5IQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpt.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FM%25C3%25A9todo_(programa%25C3%25A7%25C3%25A3o)&usg=AOvVaw23r7WozE9BBuYEsHf5Fqb-))

```
def funcao_sem_retorno():
    print("Só to aqui pra dar um oi")

def retornar_calculo_complexo(a, b):
    return a + b

print( funcao_sem_retorno() )

resultado = retornar_calculo_complexo(1, 1)
print( resultado )
```

Uma ótima fonte para estudos: [Programação Orientada a Objeto Python](https://wiki.python.org.br/ProgramacaoOrientadaObjetoPython#Python_e_Programa.2BAOcA4w-o_Orientada_a_Objeto)

Comment: Oi Guilherme - desculpe, mas essa resposta tem vários erros conceituais - então tenho que dar um downvote. 

Em particular um "objeto" em Python não é um dicionário. Em javascript as duas coisas sao equivalentes, mas em Python são *bem* diferentes.

As suas definições de atributo e método _também_ estão erradas, e a de classe embora não esteja errada se apega a forma da declaração, e não ao siginificado do que é "ser" uma classe.

Comment: Dei uma editada lá. Realmente confundi com Javascript a questão de objetos e dicionários. Fiz umas alterações, a ideia é ser uma resposta simples e objetiva. Sem muito texto e lero lero, isso pode tirar a vontade do leitor de querer entender. Abs e obrigado pelo feedback.